# Greasemonkey @require jQuery not working "Component not available"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I've seen [the other question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey) about loading jQuery in a Greasemonkey. Having tried that method, with this require statement inside my `==UserScript==` tags:

```
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

I still get the following error message in Firefox's error console:

```
Error: Component is not available
Source File: file:///Users/greg/Library/Application%20Support/
       Firefox/Profiles/xo9xhovo.default/gm_scripts/myscript/jquerymin.js
Line: 36
```

This stops my greasemonkey code from running. I've made sure I included the `@require` for jQuery and saved my js file before installing it, as required files are only loaded on installation.

Code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           My Script
// @namespace      http://www.google.com
// @description    My test script
// @include        http://www.google.com
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

GM_log("Hello");
```

I have Greasemonkey 0.8.20091209.4 installed on Firefox 3.5.7 on my Macbook Pro, Leopard (10.5.8). I've cleared my cache (except cookies) and have disabled all other plugins except Flashblock 1.5.11.2, Web Developer 1.1.8 and Adblock Plus 1.1.3.

My `config.xml` with my Greasemonkey script installed:

```
<UserScriptConfig>
<Script filename="myscript.user.js" name="My Script" 
 namespace="http://www.google.com" description="My test script" enabled="true" 
 basedir="myscript">
    <Include>http://www.google.com</Include>
    <Require filename="jquerymin.js"/>
</Script>
```

I can see jquerymin.js sat in the `gm_scripts/myscript/` directory.

Additionally, is it common for this error to occur in the console when installing a Greasemonkey script?

```
Error: not well-formed
Source File: file:///Users/Greg/Documents/myscript.user.js
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
   // ==UserScript==
```

Comment: I tried your script, it worked just fine. No problem here, using Greasemonkey version 0.8.20091129.3. Are you sure you properly uninstalled the previous script before installing the new one. I also have had troubles with caching in Firefox.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with jquery 1.4, just released a couple of days ago. At least, I have the same problem with jquery 1.4 but not with jquery 1.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so i looked into this a bit more deeper. I used your script exactly, but used our JQuery version, making it look like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           My Script
// @namespace      http://www.google.com
// @description    My test script
// @include        http://www.google.se/*
// @include        http://www.dn.se/*
// @require        http://myserver/jquery-1.3.2.js
// ==/UserScript==

GM_log("Hello");
```

This works just fine for me, my guess, the JQuery up on the google api is missing some functions. Because this code above, works just fine. Also note the `/*` at the end of each url, please include that.

Try another JQuery and change the urls and it should world properly.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my require URL to http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js and it works!

Answer (score 7):

I found a non-ideal way to use it with jQuery 1.4.1 -- this seems to fix it. It's the [new browser sniffing](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/importing-jquery-1-4-1-into-greasemonkey-scripts-generates-an-error) that seems to "break" it.

jquery-1.4.1.min.js:

```
  [old]  36: var o=r.createElement("div");n="on"+n;var m=n in o;
  [new]  36: var o=r.createElement("div");n="on"+n;var m=true;
```

jquery-1.4.1.js

```
  [old] 934: var isSupported = (eventName in el);
  [new] 934: var isSupported = true;
```

Answer (score 6):

I was stumbling around trying to deal with this issue with GM 0.8 and jquery 1.4.2 and found this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/importing-jquery-1-4-1-into-greasemonkey-scripts-generates-an-error

It looks to me like the definitive answer to the question and how to work around it.  The workaround worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for linking that, going forward this is the definitive answer (ichau also mentioned the same fix but without a link).

At the time I asked this question, 1.4 was only just out and I was using 1.3.2 for which Anders answer addressed my issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I edited mine to include the link just in case. Didn't have a link at the time and copied some comments from my script over :)

Answer (score 3):

Good news and updating all postings:

The above patch allowed pre-1.5.2 jQuery versions to be run in Greasemonkey scripts, but fortunately the patch is no longer required if you use the current jQuery 1.5.2 version.

I checked its code and noticed that the eventSupported function code in jQuery

```
var eventSupported = function(eventName) { ... }
```

has been updated with the consequence that unpatched jQuery 1.5.2 now runs in Greasemonkey 0.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

Patch for jquery-1.4.3.min.js

> [old] line 41 
>   u.createElement("div");s="on"+s;var
>   B=s in v;
>  [new] line 41 
>   u.createElement("div");s="on"+s;var
>   B=true;

Answer (score 0):

The @require attribute doesn't work correctly in Greasemonkey and jQuery...this same error can occur in FireBug as well.

An alternative is to include jQuery in the page via Greasemonkey by creating the script tag.  [Here's how to do that](http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/).

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that link - I'd like to know why @require is a documented method but isn't working for me.

http://www.keyvan.net/2008/10/greasemonkey-jquery/

Comment: We are using Greasemonkey with the @require attribute for JQuery and it works just fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely true, it seems like jQuery 1.4 tries to detect something using a call that just doesn't work in the greasemonkey environment. @require does normally work as it should.

So reverting to 1.3.2 does do the trick, but I'd rather find a solution that lets me use 1.4.

btw, I use this, slightly different:

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minified version of jQuery 1.4.4 for Greasemonkey:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/92329

Hope it helps,
yah