# Copy content from copy-blocked website using userscript (Tampermonkey)

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to copy some content from a website that has copy disabled by this part

```js
$(document).bind('copy', function(e){
      return false;
});
```

I tried to unbind the function with `$(document).off('copy')`, and it works flawlessly in the console, but when in userscript it does not work.

I used Tampermonkey userscript to create a button to copy all content from a class with these lines

```js
// Everything in this code block works in the console...
$(document).off('copy');
range.selectNode(document.getElementsByClassName('bbWrapper')[0]);
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

Already have this in header `// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js`

Also done this `var $ = window.jQuery;`

Comment: Remove `@require` and add `// @grant none` so the script will use jquery of the site.

Comment: @wOxxOm `// @grant none` has been there the whole time. I didn't delete it.

I managed to get it right by using `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js` instead of `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js`.

Thanks to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852406/20301238)

Comment: Note that `@grant none` is ignored if you have other `@grant` values.

Comment: There are no other grant values. I didn't add anything other than the require line.

Comment: In that case there should be no need to require jquery.

Comment: @wOxxOm It said `$ is not defined` (or something like that, I don't remember). When using `window.jQuery`, it said `window.jQuery is not a function`. It only work if I `@require` a jQuery.js from somewhere else.

Comment: It means the site doesn't have jQuery or it uses `jQuery` not `$` or you have another `@grant` or there's a typo. An alternative method of accessing site's jquery is `unsafeWindow.jQuery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I can't use `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js`. But thanks to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852406), I changed the link to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js`. And it worked.