# Greasemonkey @require does not work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to add jQuery using Greasemonkey's `@require` / `@include` method, but it doesn't work. The following error shows up:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (repeated 10 times)
```

This is my sample code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @description Bored, really bored.
// @name MatteoSample
// @namespace MatteoSampleNamespace
// @include *
// @include       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).slideUp();
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@ic` is not a valid meta-rule, so it's ignored.
Use [`@require`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require) if you want to load jQuery in your user script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Foo
// @namespace  Bar
// @include    *
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

EDIT: In the comments, you said that you're using **Chrome**. Chrome does **not** support the `@require` rule. See also:

- GreaseSpot Wiki: [Cross-browser userscripting](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Cross-browser_userscripting)
- Stack Overflow: [Why doesn't jQuery work in Chrome user scripts (Greasemonkey)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588513/why-doesnt-jquery-work-in-chrome-user-scripts-greasemonkey)
- Stack Overflow: [How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey scripts in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome)

If you want full Greasemonkey support in Chrome, use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

### Clearing up confusion about User scripts in Chrome

Chrome does **not** natively support GreaseMonkey. Whenever a `.user.js` file is loaded, it's converted to a Chrome extension in form of a [Content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

For more information on User scripts in Chrome, see [this documentation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts).

The User script is literally copied into the extension's directory:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Foo
// @namespace  Bar
// @include    *
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
alert(typeof $)
```

A [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) file is created, based on the meta block. When the User script contains a `@include` rule, its `matches` rule will contain `https://*/*` and `http://*/*`, because of the too loose `@include` rule.

The contents of the generated `manifest.json` looks like:

```
{
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "exclude_globs": [  ],
      "include_globs": [ "*" ],
      "js": [ "script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
   "converted_from_user_script": true,
   "description": "",
   "key": "+.... some key ...=",
   "name": "Foo",
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's an error i met while pasting. i was using @include, sorry!

Comment: @MatteoMosconi You should not use `@include`, but **`@require`** to load externals.

Comment: sorry, even trying using your meta block i see no changes :'(

Comment: thanks. I'm using the latest version of Chrome: it should alredy have greasemonkey on it. After i installed your extension ( and removed the mine ) i see some "undefined" alerts in each site. But unfortunally, i still see the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)". - What should i do to solve this? Thank you ..

Comment: What's bad? Chrome now have greasmonkey built in!

Comment: @MatteoMosconi That is wrong. See my updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

chrome doesn't support greasemonkey scripts, rather, specific greasemonkey commands 
(@require, GM_  etc)

to get that stuff working, install chrome addon "TamperMonkey"