# Retrieve only a part of remote URL in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have tried searching on Google and also read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest)  but no success. I am making the ajax request  in contentScript (chrome extension) or otherwise known as greasemonkey script for firefox users.

A typical function to get a URL using AJAX,

```
function getURL(url, element)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   
        if ( request.readyState == 4 ) 
        {   
            callback( request.responseText, element, request.status );    
        }   
    };  
    request.open( "GET", url, true );
    request.send()
}
```

Lets say **I only need first 10kb of the page** but the `whole size of page is more than 200kb`. The page I am retrieving is a normal HTML. I don't want to `waste the bandwidth by downloading the excess 190kb`. Is there any way to achieve that? Also, if retrieving only a part of page from 100kb to 110kb possible?

I am open for browser specific solution (chrome). And I have to port the extension to Firefox too so ideas about that is also welcome.

Comment: "No".

I dont think there is any way to get 'part' of a page by ajax.
You will have to fetch the whole page.

jQuey.load does this but as far as I know, it actually downloads the whole page and then filter out the desired content.

Comment: PS. Content Script are **not** Greasemonkey scripts. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9791647/938089?greasemonkey-require-does-not-work-in-chrome).

Comment: A browser-specific solution won't save you bandwidth - in order to save bandwidth the server needs to send you less data (meaning that the important part here is the server, not the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting Rob W's answer so there is a working example for this question.
The following code can be used to download the first 10k of a sites html as per the first part of the question...

> Lets say I only need first 10kb of the page

```
function getURL(url, limit, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( request.readyState == 4 ) {
            if (request.responseText!=0) callback( request.responseText, request.status );
        } else if (request.responseText.length >= limit) {
            // If limit is exceeded
            var result = request.responseText;
            request.abort(); // Cancel request
            callback( result, request.status );
        }
    };
    request.overrideMimeType("text/html");
    request.open( "GET", url, true );
    request.send();
}

getURL('http://www.google.com.au', 100000, debug);
//getURL('http://paez.kodingen.com/testy.png', 100000, debug);

function debug(responseText, status) {
    console.debug('length of responseText '+responseText.length);
    console.debug('responseStatus : '+status);
    console.debug('responseText :\n'+responseText);
}
```

**Note**
It should be noted that this wont get exactly the size you specify as their is no way to say how often the readystate will be called.  Also, I force it to be text otherwise their may not be a responseText.

Comment: Can you please elaborate `It should be noted that this wont get exactly the size you specify as their is no way to say how often the readystate will be called.`? Please elaborate why we need `request.responseText.length >= limit` part. I noticed that different sizes are being downloaded everytime I run the script. I know that you are saying something about this but I would appreciate a more elaborate explanation. Thanks.

Comment: If its not readyState==4 then its most likely a readyState==3 which is Loading.  This happens regularly during the download of the file (I couldnt find anything saying how often it should happen).  Each time it happens responseText will contain the currently downloaded data, so we keep checking to see if the length of it is past what you requested and then abort....hope that explains it.

Answer (score 7):

You can send a [`Range` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2):

```
request.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=0-9999");
request.send(null);
```

Note that the server might ignore this header and you will get the usual response back. In most cases the response will be "206 Partial Content" however with exactly 10000 bytes of data. [`Content-Range` response header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) indicates which part of the file you've got, e.g. `request.getResponseHeader("Content-Range")` might give you `bytes 0-9999/1234567` (here 1234567 is the total size of the file).

Obviously, you can also do `request.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=100000-119999");` to get data from the middle of the file.

Comment: More information here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00

Comment: @Wladimir Adding this gives `Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11` on the line where I set the `Range header`. Any idea?

Comment: nisc: ancient spec. Please stop citing it. The latest official spec is RFC 2616.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Thanks. Although the site I am working ignored the Range header for html pages, so I guess there is no way of doing it in my case.

Comment: So you give a tick to the one that doesnt work and Rob W's answer that did work people give a -1 to?.... hilarious

Comment: @WladimirPalant There was one small error with his code, but the concept completely works....I know because I have a test extension here right now that works.

Comment: Real knowledge isnt based on beliefs, but facts ;P