# Any hosted versions of jQuery that have the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header set?

Tags: jquery, same-origin-policy

I have been working with jQuery recently and ran into a problem where I couldn't include it in a userscript because XmlHttpRequest uses the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). After further testing I found that most browsers also support the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) access control defined by W3C as a workaround for issues with same origin policy. I tested this by hosting the jQuery script on a local web server that included the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` http header, which allowed the script to be downloaded using XmlHttpRequest so that it could be included in my userscript. I'd like to use a hosted version of jQuery when releasing the script, but so far testing with tools like http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers I have not found any sites that allow cross-origin access to the jQuery script. Here is the list I have tested so far:

- http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDN.ashx
- http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery
- http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Are there any other hosted versions of jQuery that do allow cross origin access? I know that jQuery is usually loaded via a script tag (sometimes a dynamically created script tag), but in this specific case I have to use XmlHttpRequest and Eval to make sure it gets loaded into the correct scope. Google Chrome supports user scripts but does not support @require, which means the only way to use [jquery in a user script in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/include-jquery-inside-greasemonkey-script-under-google-chrome/2626067#2626067) is to embed it into the .user.js file or load and eval it via an XmlHttpRequest. Embedding is a less than optimal solution, and while Chrome Extensions allow you to include the jQuery js files in extensions I would prefer to stick with user scripts since they are much simpler and can work in more than just one browser. I have already submitted tickets with both the [Google Ajax APIs](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=427) and [jQuery](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cdn-hosted-jquery-does-not-allow-cross-domain-origin-access) teams to allow cross domain access to the CDN, but my guess is that I'll just have to host it myself for now.

Comment: Why do you need to import jQuery via XMLHttpRequest?  Why not just create a script tag for it?

Comment: @Pointy I updated the question with more information, but long story short is I am trying to create a user script with jQuery that works on both Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Honestly man, There are some times that using your own hosting is a good game plan: it looks like this is one of them. Just make sure it's good and cached, it's not like jQuery is a humongous file.

Comment: @Kyle. Yeah, I figured that might be the case but thought I'd ask anyway. It is a common problem when using Greasemonkey scripts in Google Chrome, so my hope was to write 2-3 lines of JS that could be added to scripts to support Chrome, but that doesn't really work as well if I have to host jQuery myself. It's not just the bandwith, as telling people to load jQuery from Google/jQuery CDN is much different than telling them to download it from my personal website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked this question, the Google CDN has added these headers as requested. A quick GET of https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js yields the header:

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
```

So add a script tag like this and you're good to go:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, and my solution ended up being to host the file myself. With my own hosting, I could allow cross-domain requests for the jQuery script.

I tried to jump through a lot of hoops to work around this, and spent too many hours trying to hunt down and try script hosts that allowed cross-domain access. Eventually, though, I came to the conclusion that if I'm going to rely on some unknown hosted version of the script, I might as well host it myself, because I trust myself more than the hosts I was considering.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Cloudfront allows you to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Basically, if you host jQuery yourself then stick a Cloudfront CDN in front of it, Cloudfront will relay any headers you set back to the client:

```
your jQuery -> Cloudfront jQuery -> Client Browser
[header set]   [header set]         [header set]
```

The Cloudfront CDN is set up per Amazon user; the disadvantage of this compared to say the hosted Google APIs is that first-time visitors to your site won't have loaded up jQuery by visiting another site (and therefore benefit from the caching.)