# testing jQuery statements in Chrome JavaScript console

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to change a checkbox value from chrome JavaScript console. I'm aware that changes are printed to object and not on screen. I'd like to execute a jQuery statement, i.e.:

```
('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);
```

Is there any way to enter a jQuery statement, and and see changes instantly in the page?

Answer (score 40):

Yeah, and even if you don't have jquery available let it be :)

Edited snippet from [How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey scripts in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome)

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
```

After this go.

Comment: See also using bookmarklet. It is even nicer and compact. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9624997/805366

Comment: Failed here on latest Chrome: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://[snip]' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script" Fix: on line 2, change http to https

Comment: could I guess do in the address bar  all of that within . `javscript:!function(){........}()` . i.e. `javascript:function(){var script = document.createElement("script"); script.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"); script.addEventListener('load', function() { var script = document.createElement("script"); document.body.appendChild(script); }, false); document.body.appendChild(script);}();` . Then you can make a bookmark for it

Answer (score 6):

In chrome console you can do run any JavaScript, so if page has jQuery loaded, you can access the element and check/uncheck it e.g. stackoverflow.com (this site) uses jQuery so I can just access answer textarea and enter a value, try this

```
$('#wmd-input').val('This is my answer')
```

So you can do anything which is possible in jQuery.

Comment: there is a default loaded jquery but it is limited e.g. try `$.ajax` it doesn't work by default, even though $ shows as a function and even though you can do $('html')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757627/what-is-in-chrome-console#:~:text=%24%20is%20an%20alias%20for%20document,Command%20line%20(console)%20api.

Answer (score 1):

If you got jQuery loaded in the current page, you can type jQuery command.

Just type `$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);` or whatever should work in jQuery and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=foo]').click();
```

does the same thing as clicking with your mouse.