# jQuery selectors don't work in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I can't for the life of me work this one out. I have js running and 'container state..' is a console log from the running js on the page. It's displaying a selector, but if i want to do anything within the console it just returns null. I'm assuming somehow i'm over writing jQuery function somewhere, as if i called jQuery

```
>>> $
function()
```

This is how i am calling a selector

```
Container state 3 jQuery(div.module-carousel)
>>> $('body')
null
```

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded? Are you calling `jQuery.noConflict()` anywhere?

Comment: Try `jQuery('body')` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: arghh suger :p so somebody has changed the reference to jquery! yawn

Comment: Yes, it looks like jQuery function is overwritten: `.find` for selectors that cannot be found still return an (empty) array, not `null`. What other scripts are loaded?

Comment: its a new site that i'm coming into. So its a pretty big build, 53 js files are being loaded so :| i think for the time being using the console for jquery will just have to be done the safe way, jquery()

Comment: try to log the `$` function. If it gives something like `function(a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}`, it is jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Picked the most complete one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery uses 2 namespaces, `jQuery` and `$`. Another library could have used the `$`. Try using `jQuery` instead of `$` (assuming that it isn't overridden as well):

```
jQuery('body');
```

or wrap jQuery in an immediate function and use `$` in it so you don't need to replace `$` in the existing code:

```
(function($){
    //"$" in here is jQuery
    //code that uses $ as jQuery will work in here
}(jQuery)); //pass in jQuery and execute
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use this before writing any command on console.

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `$` is overloaded (but not `jQuery`), and you want to work in your console, just do the following:

```
$ = jQuery;
```

As simple as that.

For a more complete solution (real development, not just console), use [@Joseph the Dreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11242700/851498)'s solution.

Comment: if a page has jQuery already under a different var name.. say 'jqry'. How can i find this 'jqry' var name in console.. without going through html source. e.g. i want to type 'jQuery(show me var name)' should print out 'jqry' in the chrome console. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Both Firefox and Chrome define `$` as a shorthand for `document.getElementById` in the console. This shorthand will automatically be overridden when the page defines `$`.

So, load jQuery ([through a bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624997/938089?command-for-loading-jquery-on-google-chrome-inspector) for example) and you can use jQuery selectors.

If you don't need jQuery-specific selectors, you can also use `$$`, which is a shorthand for `document.querySelectorAll`, which supports CSS(3) selectors.