# Why does jQuery select the wrong element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 jQuery select expressions:

```
(1) $('html body table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) table tbody tr td table:nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(2) td table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)')
```

vs

```
(2) $('html body table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td')
```

As I can understand the first one is more specified than the second one, so if (1) returns an element it must be also included in the (2) return. May be the (2) can have more than 1 element (as in my case), so it should return an array of matched elements, isn't right? Instead it returns some fully different element, and only one (actually it returns only the first match, but not all matched, including that one, that match the (1) select expression too). Do I misunderstand any select concepts of css/jquery-selectors?

### Update 1:

The page I try to select in is:

http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=hello

### Update 2:

the selectors I have - this is the result of chrome's `get xpath` tool (just wanted to get quick a good selector for jquery)

Comment: Holy COW. That's the biggest selector ive seen in my life.

Comment: Can't you just like add a class or id or something?

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to include every element in the path in the selector. The descendant selector exists for a reason.  `$('body > table table table table td')` would do fine, but even that is not pretty.

Comment: Also, nested tables. 4 of them...

Comment: why don't you just add a class to the td and do `$('td.so-much-simpler')`

Comment: In what browser are you testing this? CSS selectors sometimes have very different support in different browsers, namely Internet Explorer. Your premise seems correct, but I'm pretty sure it's not related to the CSS itself.

Comment: @kennypu `$('.so-much-simpler')` would be even more simpler :)

Comment: @passionateCoder :) I just get it through get-xpath in chrome-dev-tools context-menu and wanted just check, if it works

Comment: @passionateCoder might as well just make it `$('.so')` :)

Comment: Using `$('your stuff').length` will show you how many elements it matched.

Comment: @Joum the browser I use is Chrome

Comment: @kennypu i was also over-qualifying selectors some days ago. Then, i saw this : http://jsperf.com/jquery-standards-over-qualified-selectors

Comment: Sure, this isn't either pretty/functional/good practice, but technically, it _should_ work as the asker explained...

Comment: @RenéWolferink $('my stuff').length is undefined

Comment: @passionateCoder so over qualifying takes more time to type AND performs worse? good thing i'm lazy

Comment: @static : That clears things up a bit. :)

Comment: @kennypu : yeah i guess. and since the selector search is done from **right->left**, you'll be giving the JS compiler more hurdles to jump. :)

Comment: @static that's really weird, then... Can't actually help you, sorry. But I would suggest taking the hint from all of these comments and get the problem solved like passionateCoder suggested and then try to figure out the CSS selector quirk. Actually, I'm not really sure if there isn't a selector depth limit or restriction...

Comment: Tables are for tabular data - not design

Comment: @kennypu what do you mean under "AND"?

Comment: @Pete :) I didn't design it, or what do you mean about tables?

Comment: @passionateCoder some bad thing? :)

Comment: @static please mention in your question that this is the result of a `get-xpath` from Chrome dev tools :)

Comment: why you use very big selector like that @.@?

Comment: @Stiger it is a chrome's `get-xpath`, just wanted to get quick the selector for jquery

Comment: Can you guys please slow down with the comments.

Comment: @FelixKling $('body > table table table table') has the same problem: it returns only the first matched element, not all mathed elements

Comment: Wait, why on earth would Chrome return a selector if you're trying to get XPath in the first place? XPath are not selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock the expression you get with XPath is a selector (wikipedia XPath defenition). You can convert this selector in css-selector (at least they have common selectors)

Comment: @static: I didn't mean that this solves the problem. But it is the equivalent selector and shorter ;)

Comment: Your page is an `.exe`?

Comment: it is a CGI. so the page is generated with the data from m.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the page you have linked you don't seem to have jQuery loaded that I can see. You have a `$` object but many things use that abbreviation. There doesn't seem to be a `jQuery` object on the page though which leads me to believe that whatever you have on that page is not jQuery.

Comment: great investigation! it is really something strange there with $, but definitely not a jQuery. I loaded jQuery additionally with the help of script from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624972/command-for-loading-jquery-on-google-chrome-inspector) so it works now as expected (e.g. `jQuery('body > table table table table')` returns now a collection of html elements)

Comment: It was my first thought when I saw it wasn't returning what I expected and then when I realised it didn't have the right functions on the object it was the obvious conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors always return collections of elements, even if there is only one. Methods that logically work with only one element will work only with the first element of the collection, even if invoked on a collection with more than one element. You can check the number of elements in your collection with the good old-fashioned .length property or the modern oo-fanatic .size() method. Both will return the same result.

You can iterate through a collection using good old for structure and access the current element with collection.eq(i). Alternately and preferably, you can execute a function on each element of the collection with collection.each(func). Function func will have the current element available as this.

And, seriously, you don't need to specify every element in the DOM tree in a selector. Of course jQuery will search in html and body because there's no other way in a proper html file. Best practice is to include minimal number of selectors needed to uniquely identify your element or elements you want to select. Never specify html and body. Never have two ids in your selector. Don't specify tbody unless the element you need can also occur in thead or tfoot and you don't need those occurrences. Things like that.

Comment: somehow it doesn't return a collection, where I could call a size() or length. even with suggested $('body > table table table table td') selector