# Clicking on an element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to use Jquery (for the first time actually) in order to click on a picture on the Google Images search page ([example search page](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=dsaasd&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=EwvEUaAi5KbgBOKPgcAE&biw=1280&bih=899&sei=FQvEUfL5MOWx0AWSxoDADw#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=xvxcv&oq=xvxcv&gs_l=img.12..0i10i24l5.348618.349968.6.510248.2.2.0.0.0.0.122.237.0j2.2.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.img.GqaDFgNGM9k&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48293060,d.d2k&fp=3f28af5c18c25e6&biw=1280&bih=596)). I do the following:

```
allPictures = $(".rg_di");
picture = allPictures[0];
picture.click();
```

I expect it to behave as if I clicked the picture, but it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: How would you get your code running in the Google image search page?

Comment: Clicking an image would do nothing anyway, unless an events attached to it. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Stefan relaying the search result with a local proxy where you can overcome xss :)

Comment: @Stefan, I did it using the Chrome console

Comment: @Curt, I expect it to do the same thing it does when I click the picture "manually" - open a window

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger a click (event):

```
picture.trigger('click');
```

Further I would recommend to use:

```
allPictures.first()
```

instead of:

```
allPictures[0];
```

Comment: The object has no "trigger" method..

Comment: Google Chrome Console != jQuery

Comment: You could load jQuery on Google Image search according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624972/command-for-loading-jquery-on-google-chrome-inspector

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're searching for the incorrect class name on the google search results for the class attached to the image (the class selector in the question is for the surrounding div):

```
var aPicture = $(".rg_i");
aPicture.click()
```

Will select the first image in the results.

Answer (score 1):

picture is not a jquery object

you need
    $(picture).click();

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this with the google chrome consode, you can write:

```
$('.rg_bb_layout').click();
```

to open the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Four images on document load click first

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKG25/)

html

```
<a onclick="alert('test1')" class="rg_di">
    <img src="http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/182/xvxcv.jpg" height="200" width="200"/>
</a>
<a onclick="alert('test2')" class="rg_di">
    <img src="http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/182/xvxcv.jpg" height="200" width="200"/>
</a>
<a onclick="alert('test3')" class="rg_di">
    <img src="http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/182/xvxcv.jpg" height="200" width="200"/>
</a>
<a onclick="alert('test4')" class="rg_di">
    <img src="http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/182/xvxcv.jpg" height="200" width="200"/>
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var allPictures = $(".rg_di");
    var picture = allPictures[0];
    picture.click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to attach jquery on the current page.Type it in the console(Ctrl+Shift+I to open the console)

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

`$('.rg_i').click();` or any other way as posted by others to trigger a click event on the image.