# Selecting <option> of a <select> from a Chrome extension content script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events, content-script

I'm hopelessly trying to activate a `change()` event from a Chrome content script.
I've gone past through of the web site and Google posts, but still nothing works.

Here's a description of what I'm trying to achieve;

Consider the following web page (reachable via http://www.gilzu.com/TFF/select.html should someone be so kind to help):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#woot').die('change');
            $('#woot').live('change', function () {
                $('#description').text(jQuery('#woot').val());
                });
            console.log("window ready");       
        
            
            $("#meh").click(function() {
                $('#woot').val(15);
                $('#woot').change();
            });
            
            $('#woot').val(21);
            $('#woot').change();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <select id="woot">
            <option id="Option1" value="15">a</option>
            <option id="Option2" value="16">b</option>
            <option id="Option3" value="17">c</option>
            <option id="Option4" value="18">d</option>
            <option id="Option5" value="19">e</option>
            <option id="Option6" value="20">f</option>
            <option id="Option7" value="21">g</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    
    <p id="description"></p>
    <p><input type="button" id="meh" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What DO work:

1. on startup the `change()` fires up and updates the selection box to 21 and shows right value on the div.
2. pressing on the button #meh, changes the selection box to 15, triggers the `change()` event that shows the right value on the screen.

No surprise so far.

So I'm heading to the content script via:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#woot').val(17);
                $('#woot').change();
                });
```

so the select tag updates, but the `change()` event does not trigger.

I've read the forum about Chrome's extension isolated worlds and put this theory to the test:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#meh").click();
});
```

and it in fact triggers both the click event AND the change event of the select box!

Also, to contradict another post claiming that code injection of the js works:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var x = $("<script type='text/javascript' />");
    $(x).text("$('#woot').val(18); $('#woot').change();");
    $("head").append(x);        
});
```

Issues the same effect: select box updates but change event does not fire.

I've also tried the following:

1. creating a button such as the example's `#meh` with an attached click event that triggers the select tag's `change()`. only the select updates, no event fires.
2. changing the value of the select box via `attr()`, `prop()`, `val()`  only the select updates, no event fires.
3. firing the event via `change()`, trigger('change') and `selectedIndex`  only the select updates, no event fires.
4. delaying the command via js
5. using `focus()` another control, this control or even `blur()` the select box as some posts suggest.

your help will be most appreciated

Comment: Note: Content scripts *do* run in an isolated context, where they can only access the DOM of a page. The page's `window` object is not directly accessible, but `document` is.

Comment: Try injecting your script into the page... I [posted an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/8890387#8890387) related to Greasemonkey, but it should work here as well.

Comment: @fudgey - check the last code. exactly what u said only in jQuery. updates the select but doesnt fire the event.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dont really know JQuery, but here's how to do it without JQuery and without injecting anything into the page....

```
var selections = document.querySelector('#woot');

selections.value = 17;

var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
selections.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: fantastic! it works and far more elegant than injecting code :)

Comment: Thanks! but why can not jquery do this?

Comment: @dev-siberia  Im sure you could, but I dont, so I didnt.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a script. It'll take a lot of script appends but you can always put a custom communication event, and only inject one good script listening to that custom event and `eval()`ing the event data. It will work if there's no CSP.

```
var RunInThisContext = function(c){ try{
    var code = document.createTextNode(c);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.language='javascript';
    script.appendChild(code);
    try{document.body.appendChild(script);}catch(e){document.head.appendChild(script);}

}catch(e){ console.error('ERROR: '+e); }};
```

Use like this:

```
RunInThisContext('('+(function(){ 
     $('select').change();
}).toString()+'()); ');
```

But bear in mind you're running this directly into the page. If page doesn't have jQuery you'll have to include it first.

Comment: why is this different from the last piece of code in the question ? he injected JS into the page's head element.

Comment: EDIT (5 min are up): well, you are correct, i just tested this to work. +1

Comment: @Menahem jQuery's `append()/appendTo()` with script tag takes control over the execution of that script which will cause jQuery to execute the script inside the content script's isolated context.

Comment: thanks for the reply. if you can spare the time to explain,how is the way you did it different from the way it's done in the last piece of code in the question ?

Comment: @Menahem grosso-modo when you do `$('<script>')` jQuery takes it, creates an invisible div, appends the html code to the document and tries to compute dom tree, styles, width/height values, etc. This step unfortunately also interprets the scripts. This is the difference.