# running site function from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, document

thats what i got so far

```
function onReady(callback) {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") window.setTimeout(callback, 0);
    else window.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
}
onReady(function() {
    removeit("new");
});

function removeit() {
    el = document.querySelector("#toolbarCurtain");
    if (el) {
        el.style.setProperty("display", "", null);
    } * * EXEC COMMAND
    return;
}
```

the "   **EXEC COMMAND" thing is where i want to call a function that is in the site itself. the function is called drawPlayer(), and when i type drawPlayer() in the chrome console it works. i can't make my script call the function, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388087/608886).

All injected code runs in an isolated world, a javascript context isolated from the main website's JS context. This is a built-in security measure and cannot be disabled.

The solution is to append a script. If you need a lot of executions, you should normally setup a custom communication event, and only inject one script listening to that custom event and `eval()`ing the event data. [Here is how Google recommends to do this.](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication)

Bear in mind this will only work if the target site doesn't have CSP (Content-Security-Policy).

```
var RunInThisContext = function(c){ 
    var code = document.createTextNode(c);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.appendChild(code);
    document.body.appendChild(script);      
};
```

Use like this:

```
RunInThisContext('('+(function(){ 
     /////////////////////
     //
     //   RUN YOUR FUNCTIONS HERE
     //
     /////////////////////
}).toString()+'()); ');
```