# How can I get my cross-domain Greasemonkey script to work in Chrome, even though it requires jQuery and Greasemonkey API functions?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-domain, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm fighting to get a userscript to work on chrome. I know this question has been asked hundreds of times but I still can't get it to work...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        SRH hide closed cases
// @namespace   srhhideclosed
// @description For hiding appeals and reports that have been closed
// @include     http://www.seriousroleplayinghell.com*
// @include     http://seriousroleplayinghell.com*
// @include     http://www.srh.im.com*
// @include     http://srh.im.com*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

// Insert GM API for chrome
if (typeof GM_deleteValue == 'undefined') {
    GM_addStyle = function(css) {
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = css;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    }

    GM_deleteValue = function(name) {
        localStorage.removeItem(name);
    }

    GM_getValue = function(name, defaultValue) {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(name);
        if (!value)
            return defaultValue;
        var type = value[0];
        value = value.substring(1);
        switch (type) {
            case 'b':
                return value == 'true';
            case 'n':
                return Number(value);
            default:
                return value;
        }
    }

    GM_log = function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }

    GM_openInTab = function(url) {
        return window.open(url, "_blank");
    }

     GM_registerMenuCommand = function(name, funk) {
    //todo
    }

    GM_setValue = function(name, value) {
        value = (typeof value)[0] + value;
        localStorage.setItem(name, value);
    }
}

function toggleHidden(){
    if(GM_getValue("SRHhidden",0) == 1){
        GM_setValue("SRHhidden", 0);
    }else{
        GM_setValue("SRHhidden", 1);
    }
    hide(1000)
}

function hide(speed){
    if(GM_getValue("SRHhidden",0) == 1){
        $('s').closest('tr').fadeIn(speed);
    }else{
        $('s').closest('tr').fadeOut(speed);
    }
}

if(document.title == "Serious Roleplaying Hell - Appeals" || document.title == "Serious Roleplaying Hell - Admin/Player Abuse Reports" ){
    var TDHeads = document.getElementsByClassName("thead");
    var Head = TDHeads[1];
    var sp1 = document.createElement("div");
    sp1.style.cssFloat = "right";
    sp1.style.margin = "0 0 0 6px";
    sp1.innerHTML = "<span class='smalltext'><strong>| <a id='hideToggle'>Hide/Show closed threads</a></strong></span>";
    Head.insertBefore(sp1, Head.firstChild);
    var toggle = document.getElementById('hideToggle');
    toggle.addEventListener('click',toggleHidden,true);
    var style = "#hideToggle:hover{cursor:pointer} #hideToggle{color:#ffffff;}"
    GM_addStyle(style);

    hide(0);
}
```

So what does it need to do, there is this forum that shows threads subjects striped if the thread is closed. For a reason I need to hide all the closed once so I can review only the open threads. I have this script running on Firefox, but `@require` is not supported by Chrome.

I've tried [How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey scripts in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome) and [How to play nicely with jQuery and Greasemonkey](http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/).
But, I can get neither to work in Chrome.
Anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tampermonkey instead of opening it as a extension works

Comment: Yes, Tampermonkey is the smartest easiest way, all around for FF+Chrome scripting.  Even if you got jQuery working, which [this answers does nicely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508), you would have found that those `GM_`-function fakes didn't work properly, due to this script running on multiple domains.

Comment: @Bronk Adams, Sure the GM-function don't save cross domain, but most users don't use all 4 of the domains. they are just aliases of the same website anyway.