# In a userscript, is there any advantage to using querySelector() vs jQuery's $()?

Tags: jquery-selectors, cross-browser, css-selectors, greasemonkey, userscripts

Is there any advantage to using `querySelector()` vs jQuery's `$()` in a userscript? I want the script to work in all major browsers that support userscripts, so I'm especially interested in cross-browser compatibility.

I started to wonder about this because I noticed *honestbleeps'* excellent *Reddit Enhancement Suite* includes jQuery as a dependency, but mostly sticks to `querySelector()` for selecting elements and other basic JavaScript methods for DOM manipulation.

Is it just a matter of taste, or is there a reason to keep jQuery use to a minimum?

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into that mix in the *Reddit Enhancement Suite*.  In any big or evolving project, you'll find a mix of older-style code that (mostly) works, along with newer or better practices. (Newer is not necessarily better though.) ... Very few developers or teams will refactor old working code just to make everything consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason to use `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` is if you are not using jQuery.  jQuery selectors are more powerful and more likely to perform consistently across browsers than advanced CSS selectors.

That said, including jQuery can needlessly complicate *simple* scripts.  It requires *Script Injection* on most browsers -- which defeats sandboxes, creates potential conflicts, and makes your script dependent on a third-party server.
  [Here is a cross-browser way to include jQuery that minimizes conflicts. And, if the browser supports local jQuery copies, it doesn't require a third-party server to always be up/fast.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508)

If the script is simple and you can avoid jQuery without much effort, use `querySelector()`.  Your script will work on all script-able browsers, 99+ percent of the time.

If the script loads jQuery anyway, use jQuery selectors for maximum power and consistency.

Note that for any but the most basic DOM manipulation, jQuery is usually worth the costs.  And for Firefox+Greasemonkey or Chrome+Tampermonkey, there is almost no drawback to using jQuery if you [`@require` it](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require).

Comment: Plus, jQuery defaults to `querySelectorAll()` whenever you supply a valid CSS selector anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` [is not supported in some browser versions](http://caniuse.com/queryselector), whereas jQuery's `$()` is.

Comment: Doesn't apply for `greasemonkey` and `userscripts` questions.  All recent editions of scriptable browsers support `querySelector()`. (At least among the standard vendors)