# Userscripts, going through elements and testing attributes

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I'm kinda new to Userscripts and JavaScript in general, and I'm pretty lost.

Basically what I want to do is go through elements I got by using getElementsByClassName, get the data in the "name" attribute, see if it contains something and if so, change the class name to something else.

In pseudo-ish-code:

```
items = getElementsByClassName("item1");

for each item in items {
    if(item.attribute("name").contains("Hi"))
        item.attribute("class") = "item2";
}
```

If someone could give me some tips on how I could do this, that'd be awesome.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. See [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute), [`contains`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/1048572) and [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute)/[`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className)/[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList). If you're stuck anywhere, show us the JS code you have!

Comment: Wow, thanks! I had it almost right in my head the whole time, just needed more theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// get all items with class 'item1'
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item1');
var length = items.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // save reference to current item
    var item = items[i];
    // check if name contains 'Hi'
    if (item.getAttribute('name').indexOf('Hi') !== -1) {
        // update class
        item.className += ' item2';
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/9zBnn

Answer (score 0):

Vitaliy's answer is spot on, but it is worth mentioning that the object returned by document.querySelectorAll (a `NodeList`) can be converted to a JavaScript `Array` in order to make use of the [higher order Array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) JavaScript provides, eg:

```
// Convert the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` into an `Array`.
var items = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.item1'));

items
    .filter(function (item) {
        // Filter Array to only include items that have a name attribute
        // that beings with "Hi".
        return item.getAttribute('name').indexOf('Hi') !== -1;
    })
    .forEach(function (hiItem) {
        // Add a class to these items.
        hiItem.className += ' item2';
    });
```

Personally, I find these higher order Array functions to be much nicer to work with.

Comment: Why don't you just `[].filter.call(document.getElemntsByClassName('item1'), function(){…})`?

Comment: That would also be valid, I guess it just comes down to personal preference.  I also feel the `Array.prototype.slice.call` is a little easier for a beginner to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full power of `querySelectorAll`.  Also, use DOM methods; don't muck with the `class` attribute or `className`:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll (".item1[name*='Hi']");

for (var J = items.length-1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    items[J].classList.add ("item2");
}
```

---

---

Better yet, use [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/12751531#12751531):

```
$(".item1[name*='Hi']").addClass ("item2");
```