# unwrap() removes link in jsFiddle test, but not in Tampermonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I tried remove a link on a div, and it works using `unwrap()`, [see it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv3Fm/1/)

Now, I want implement a userscript to remove the link on a website ([example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv3Fm/2/embedded/result/)), but it's not working.

I'm using Tampermonkey. Here's my userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Remove Link
// @include        http://jsfiddle.net/dv3Fm/2/embedded/result/
// ==/UserScript==

function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {
 $('.spoiler a > .smallfont').unwrap();
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="spoiler">
    <!--I want remove link only -->
    <a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="smallfont" id="bbcode_div"/>        
        </div>
    </a>  

</div>

<!--I want result such as : -->
 <div class="spoiler">
        <div class="smallfont" id="bbcode_div"/>        
        </div> 
</div>
```

What is my userscript doing wrong? How can I remove the link using unwrap jQuery in a  userscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with that script:

1. It's including the wrong page.
2. It's injecting jQuery which conflicts with the page's own jQuery.

(1) jsFiddle loads the payload page in iframes.  For a fiddle of:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/dv3Fm/2/
```

The content iframe is (current scheme):

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dv3Fm/2/show/light/
```

So, your script must include the iframe for the content it wants to change.

(2) That target page already has jQuery, so using `addJQuery()` like that will bust either the page's jQuery or the script's jQuery, depending on the timing.

As a general rule, never use script injection (create a `<script>` tag), if you can help it!
Fortunately, Tampermonkey, and Greasemonkey provide a far-superior option in the form of [the `@require` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require).

With that (and the `@grant` directive), your script can avoid all conflicts with the page's script (and can even run, in Greasemonkey, if the page's JS is completely blocked).

Given all that, your script would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Remove Link
// @include  http://fiddle.jshell.net/dv3Fm/2/show/light/
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

$('.spoiler a > .smallfont').unwrap();
```

---

---

If you want your script to also be able to work in browsers that don't support the `@require` directive, without losing the advantages in browsers that do, use the second technique shown in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508).

But I recommend just sticking with Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey (which are almost completely code compatible).

Comment: Perfect...I thought I saw something like this before. Thanks.