# Userscript works in Firefox, but Chrome gives: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, greasemonkey, userscripts

I tried to run [this script](https://userscripts.org/scripts/review/145553) in Chrome, but it doesn't work.

Just the error **Cannot read property 'length' of null** appears.

```
if($("div.diashow").length>0&&$("div.diashow.list").length==0){

    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});

    var objContent = $("#objectContent");

    $("span.prev").remove();
    $("span.next").remove();
    $("p.next").remove();

    $("div.screen img").unwrap();

    var numOfSlides = parseInt($("span.volume").text().substr(11));    

    for(var i=2;i<=numOfSlides;i++){

        $.get("document.URL"+"?_slideNumber="+i, function(data) {

            var slidesCanvas = $("div.slidesCanvas",data);

            $("span.prev",slidesCanvas).remove();
            $("span.next",slidesCanvas).remove();
            $("p.next",slidesCanvas).remove();

            $("div.screen img",slidesCanvas).unwrap();

            objContent.append(slidesCanvas);            
        });       
    }        
}
```

I tried to fix it by myself, but with my limited javascript knowledge, I wasn't successful.  Why does this script not work in Chrome?  It works in Firefox.

[Sample target page for the script](http://derstandard.at/1369363101344/).

Comment: It looks like $ might be something's else than jQuery in your userscript.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: If i using `jQuery` instead of `$` the error `jQuery is not defined` appears.

Comment: What does your HTML look like where you'd like a match for `div.diashow`?

Comment: Like this: http://derstandard.at/1369363101344/ I'm trying to run this userscript in Google Chrome: https://userscripts.org/scripts/review/145553 (It works in Firefox fine but in Google Chrome I just get errors.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That userscript](https://userscripts.org/scripts/review/145553) uses `@require` to load jQuery, which is a good thing.
However, straight Chrome does not support `@require` (nor much of Greasemonkey's marvelous features).

So, to use that script as-is in Chrome, the smart thing to do is to **install and use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)**.  Tampermonkey has a number of advantages over a straight Chrome userscript, in ease of use, compatibility, and power.

If, you do not want to use Tampermonkey, then rewrite the script to use [this cross-browser technique for loading jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508).

Comment: Thank you, but it only works with Tapermonkey. Without Tapermonkey still get the Cannot read property 'length' of null error appears. I also see in Chrome under DevTools/Resources/Scripts that jquery.min.js successful loaded.

Comment: If you follow [the recipe I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508), it will work in Chrome. If it doesn't then that's a different error.  Post your code, modified per that recipe. But the smart thing to do is forget straight Chrome and  **Just use Tampermonkey!**