# Native javascript equivalent of jQuery :contains() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I am writing a UserScript that will remove elements from a page that contain a certain string.

If I understand jQuery's contains() function correctly, it seems like the correct tool for the job.

Unfortunately, since the page I'll be running the UserScript on does not use jQuery, I can't use :contains(). Any of you lovely people know what the native way to do this is?

http://codepen.io/coulbourne/pen/olerh

Comment: Go ahead and [add jQuery with your userscript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12751531/331508).  Don't waste time trying to recreate it in pieces.

Comment: If you're prepared to drop support for some browsers (I think just IE7 - EDIT: Also maybe IE8), you can use the native "document.querySelectorAll" in a very similar way to JQuery's selector. http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score 40):

This should do in modern browsers:

```
function contains(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return [].filter.call(elements, function(element){
    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
contains('p', 'world'); // find "p" that contain "world"
contains('p', /^world/); // find "p" that start with "world"
contains('p', /world$/i); // find "p" that end with "world", case-insensitive
...
```

Comment: Possibly use `Array.prototype.filter.call` instead of allocating a new array.

Comment: This is incorrect because it also includes results for all child nodes. I.e. if child node of `element` will contain `text` - `element` will be included into `contains` result; which is wrong.

Comment: To exclude parents element and only get last element that contain text then this script need to correct like this `return element.childNodes[0]?.nodeValue && RegExp(text).test(element.childNodes[0].textContent);`

Answer (score 11):

Super modern one-line approach with [optional chaining operator](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(element => element.childNodes?.[0]?.nodeValue?.match('❤'));
```

And better way is to search in all child nodes

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].filter(e => e.childNodes && [...e.childNodes].find(n => n.nodeValue?.match("❤")))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to implement `contains` method exaclty as jQuery does, this is what you need to have

```
function contains(elem, text) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || getText(elem)).indexOf(text) > -1;
}

function getText(elem) {
    var node,
        ret = "",
        i = 0,
        nodeType = elem.nodeType;

    if ( !nodeType ) {
        // If no nodeType, this is expected to be an array
        for ( ; (node = elem[i]); i++ ) {
            // Do not traverse comment nodes
            ret += getText( node );
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 1 || nodeType === 9 || nodeType === 11 ) {
        // Use textContent for elements
        // innerText usage removed for consistency of new lines (see #11153)
        if ( typeof elem.textContent === "string" ) {
            return elem.textContent;
        } else {
            // Traverse its children
            for ( elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling ) {
                ret += getText( elem );
            }
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 3 || nodeType === 4 ) {
        return elem.nodeValue;
    }
    // Do not include comment or processing instruction nodes

    return ret;
};
```

**SOURCE: [Sizzle.js](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/dist/sizzle.js)**

Answer (score 5):

The original question is from **2013**

###### Here is an even **older** solution, and the **fastest** solution because the main workload is done by the **Browser Engine** NOT the **JavaScript Engine**

The [TreeWalker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) has been around for ages, IE9 was the **last** browser to implement it... in **2011**

All those 'modern' and 'super-modern' `querySelectorAll("*")` need to process **all** nodes **and** do string comparisons on **every** node.

The [TreeWalker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) gives you **only the** `#text` Nodes, and then you do what you want with them.

You could also use the [NodeIterator API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator), but TreeWalker [is faster](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/5581/2/traverse-function-vs-nodeiterator-vs-treewalker#latest_results_block)

```js
  function textNodesContaining(txt, root = document.body) {
      let nodes = [],
          node, 
          tree = document.createTreeWalker(
                            root, 
                               4, // NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT
                               {
                                 node: node => RegExp(txt).test(node.data)
                               });
      while (node = tree.nextNode()) { // only return accepted nodes
        nodes.push(node);
      }
      return nodes;
  }
```

#### Usage

```
textNodesContaining(/Overflow/);

textNodesContaining("Overflow").map(x=>console.log(x.parentNode.nodeName,x));

// get "Overflow" IN A parent
textNodesContaining("Overflow")
   .filter(x=>x.parentNode.nodeName == 'A')
   .map(x=>console.log(x));

// get "Overflow" IN A ancestor
textNodesContaining("Overflow")
   .filter(x=>x.parentNode.closest('A'))
   .map(x=>console.log(x.parentNode.closest('A')));
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, jQuery comes equipped with a DOM traversing engine that operates a lot better than the one i'm about to show you, but it will do the trick.

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i].innerHTML.indexOf("word") != -1) { 
    // Do your magic
  }
}
```

Wrap it in a function if you will, but i would strongly recommend to use jQuery's implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This is the modern approach

```
function get_nodes_containing_text(selector, text) {
    const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];

    return elements.filter(
      (element) =>
        element.childNodes[0]
        && element.childNodes[0].nodeValue
        && RegExp(text, "u").test(element.childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim())
    );
  }
```