# How to select all anchor tags with specific text content with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, selectors-api

I want to use the selector in document.querySelector() to select all a tags with the text "print".

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in">print</a>
```

how can I select the same. I don't want to use jQuery. I doesn't have to be querySelector only but any other selector will do.

Comment: you need to use querySelector() or you don't want to use it ? , i didn't get you.

Comment: I meant that it's ok to use other selector forms like get elements by tag names etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var findElements = function(tag, text) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  var found = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerHTML === text) {
      found.push(elements[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return found;
}

console.log(findElements('a', 'print'));
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.in">print</a>
<a href="https://www.google.co.in">skip</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below JavaScript function,

```
function contains(selector, text) {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
   return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
     return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
   });
}
```

And call using

```
var results = contains('a', 'print'); // find "a" that contain "print"
var results = contains('a', /^print/); // find "a" that start with "print"
var results = contains('a', /print$/i); // find "a" that end with "print", case-insensitive
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37098508/3091398)

Comment: That is plagiarism. Just comment with a link

Comment: @mplungjan I know but i have mentioned the source of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

To select all anchors you should use document.querySelectorAll()

Then simply loop over the node list and check if the inner html is 'print'

Then push it to an array. This array contains all the anchor links with the text 'print'

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
var selectedLinks = []

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var link = anchors[i];

  if (link.innerHTML === 'print') {
    selectedLinks.push(link) 
  }
}
```