# Javascript Regex - to fetch specific html tag from a string of tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-group

I have a string which contains HTML TD tags. I want to construct a regex to fetch that TD which has innerHTML "Number"

Example:

Following are the whole string

```
var rows = `<td width="69" style="white-space:normal">Name</td>
<td width="70" style="white-space:normal;border-left:none">Number</td>
<td width="64" style="white-space:normal;border-left:none">Type</td>`;
```

Regex should be:
 If I put "Number" in regex, second TD tag should fetched. If I put "Name",  first TD tag should fetched.

Thank you,

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: SO is not a regexp generator. At least post some code you tried and we'll try to fix it.

Comment: Take the help of jQuery. Will ease your work.

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/gsXlab/1

```
/<td[^>]+?>Number<\/td>/g
```

Try this. But next time please try first and put your question with some code you tried.

Comment: Thanks @Dananjaya . I take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Using DOM instead of RegEx

[Javascript .querySelector find  by innerTEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37098508/295783)

Examples were not hard to find

Note you can create the fragment outside the function to reuse it

```js
var cells = `<td width="69" style="white-space:normal">Name</td>
<td width="70" style="white-space:normal;border-left:none">Number</td>
<td width="64" style="white-space:normal;border-left:none">Type</td>`;

function contains(selector, text) {
  var fragment = document.createElement("TR");
  fragment.innerHTML=cells;
  var elements = fragment.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
}

console.log("Name",contains('td', 'Name')[0]); // rmeove [0] to get more than one
console.log("Number",contains('td', 'Number')[0]);
console.log("Type",contains('td', 'Type')[0]);
```

Comment: Pretty awsm. Thanks @mplungjan