# How can I parse DOM nodes more quickly?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension content script that attempts to match strings from an array of objects with `textcontent` from html nodes. If there is a match, the extension will replace the the html that contains the match with new html.

I am having problems with the matching. The array that contains the strings is made up of 2367 objects, with each object containing a name property.

I implemented a TreeWalker to narrow down the nodes I am parsing to only those that contain text with words.

Basically, I am trying to find the intersection of nodes that contain string matches. However, every approach I have taken for this problem has results in execution times that take  5 minutes or longer and/or CPU bottlenecking. I am hoping you guys may be able to point out what I am doing wrong or send me in different direction. Thanks in advance!

So far, all my attempts at finding matches have included some implementation of RegEx. `replace()` seems to be the most taxing, but `test()` does not provide much improvement.

For looping through the array of nodes and the Array of string objects, I have tried `for..of` loops, `for` loops, `forEach()` with a nested `forEach()`, and a `filter()` with a nested `some()`.

Here is a simple version of the content script.

```
const test = (players) => {
  let body = document.body;
  let bodyCopy = body.cloneNode(true)
  let treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    bodyCopy,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    node => {

      let regex = /\w+/gi
      if (regex.test(node.textContent)) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
      } else {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
      }
    }
  );

  let nodes = [];

  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    nodes.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
  }
  const intersection = (_players, _nodes) => {
    let matchedPlayers = [];
    matchedPlayers = _players.filter(player => {
      return _nodes.some((node) => {
        let re = new RegExp(player.name.full, 'i')
        return re.test(node.textContent)
      })
    })
    console.log (matchedPlayers);
  }
  return intersection(players, nodes)
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === "test") {
      console.log(request.players)
      test(request.players)
      sendResponse({ gotIt: "Got it!" })
    }
  }
)
```

Here is what an object from the `request.players` array looks like

```
{
    "name": {
        "full": "Austin Adams",
        "first": "Austin",
        "last": "Adams",
        "ascii_first": "Austin",
        "ascii_last": "Adams",
    },
    "owned": false
}
```

Comment: You could possibly use an [XPATH query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098405/javascript-queryselector-find-div-by-innertext) on a ["synthetic" DOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) (that is, if the code isn't running in an environment where the real DOM is available). See [using XPATH with JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/wiki/Using-Google-XPath-implementation-with-jsdom)

Comment: @Olian04 Thanks Olian. XPATH looks very promising. I hadn't heard of it before. Fortunately, the nature of chrome extenstions allows me direct access to the natural DOM. I will definitely look into it. Thanks!

Comment: There are several problems. 1) you're recreating RegExp each time (the line with player.name.full). You should compile them into an array (just once) and use the result afterwards. 2) Instead of `/\w+/gi` simply check for `node.textContent.trim()` 3) Tthere's no need to clone document.body. P.S. XPath is also super slow.

Comment: @wOxxOm Wow, I really should have thought to make an array of the names first. Thanks for the suggestion. I should have mentioned that I will be eventually changing the html in numerous places after searching the through all the text nodes. My thought on cloning `document.body` was to avoid a bunch of DOM repaint and reflows and instead do all the changes at the end of the function. Admittedly, I am not sure if that will show any performance improvement.