# Internal search bar in react

Tags: reactjs

Hello to the entire stackoverflow community.

The first thing I have to say is that I am just a student and that I am starting to learn "React". With this in mind, I hope you are not too demanding of me.

After this, my question:

I am making a react with different components that basically has text inside the html tags in the render.
I would like to make a search engine that will locate any text in any component and redirect me to that point, but I don't know how to start.
I've been searching the web (with google, of course) and the truth is that I can't find anything that simply does what I want. All I find is to search in databases or queries, etc. But I can't find anything that is an internal content search engine to React.

Could someone tell me a tutorial or how to do this search engine in react?

Thank you very much for anticipating your responses.

Comment: I think this question is where you might find the answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098405/javascript-queryselector-find-div-by-innertext. Good luck!

Comment: This also seem to work. Just remember its not intended for production as its non-standard https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find