How to find a DOM object by the text using JS/Chrome extension execution?
Currently trying to access DOM object by the 'text', and I can't find this using standard javascript way - 'evaluate' or looping through all th object.
DOM object that I want to access is  with textContent <target_text>
I have confirmed that <target_text> is unique across the whole page.
Executing this as part of Chrome extension.
Target element looks like this
<th class="MuiTableCell-root table-header-cell h-8 whitespace-pre-wrap align-middle text-left MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-1bz4y89" scope="col" style="width: 50%;">Target Text</th>

So there is not unique class or tag to point it by.
It's parent look like
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-head css-16pe4ub"><th class="MuiTableCell-root table-header-cell h-8 whitespace-pre-wrap align-middle text-left MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-1bz4y89" scope="col" style="width: 50%;">Target Text</th><th class="MuiTableCell-root table-header-cell h-8 whitespace-pre-wrap align-middle text-left MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-1bz4y89" scope="col" style="width: 50%;">Finding</th><th class="MuiTableCell-root table-header-cell h-8 whitespace-pre-wrap align-middle text-left w-13 MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-1bz4y89" scope="col"></th></tr>

  const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('th');
  const targetElement = Array.from(techConcernsElements).find(th => 
    th.textContent.trim() === '<target_text>'
  );

This returns nothing
  const targetElement = document.evaluate(
    "//th[text()='<target_text>']", // This is the Xpath directly.
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, // FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE returns the first matching node
    // Other options include:
    // UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE - Returns all matching nodes in arbitrary order
    // ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE - Returns all matching nodes in document order
    // UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE - Returns snapshot of matches in arbitrary order
    // ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE - Returns snapshot of matches in document order
    // FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE - Returns first match in document order
    // ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE - Returns any single matching node
    // NUMBER_TYPE - Returns number value
    // STRING_TYPE - Returns string value
    // BOOLEAN_TYPE - Returns boolean value
    null
  );

Tried out the explicit selector found in the chrome page
#root > div.flex.flex-col.h-screen > main > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.MuiPaper-root.MuiPaper-elevation.MuiPaper-rounded.MuiPaper-elevation1.MuiCard-root.relative.overflow-visible.rounded-sm.w-full.max-w-6xl.xl\:max-w-7xl.css-1kxnsga > div.\[\&_tbody_tr_td\]\:text-lg.\[\&_th\]\:text-base > div:nth-child(2) > table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1)

via
const targetElement = document.querySelector('#root > div.flex.flex-col.h-screen > main > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.MuiPaper-root.MuiPaper-elevation.MuiPaper-rounded.MuiPaper-elevation1.MuiCard-root.relative.overflow-visible.rounded-sm.w-full.max-w-6xl.xl\\:max-w-7xl.css-1kxnsga > div\\[\\&_tbody_tr_td\\]\\:text-lg\\[\\&_th\\]\\:text-base > div:nth-child(2)');

This also returns nothing

It's possible I don't understand your question, but I just thought I'd let you know that I used @TimDown 's Rangy API to add a class to the current selection, and then (I think) I detected the node with a mutation observer

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098405/javascript-queryselector-find-div-by-innertext

Change techConcernsElements to targetElements. Have you checked what error you get using .find() on a non-existent array?

From the full html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    
    <table>
        <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-head css-16pe4ub">
            <th class="MuiTableCell-root table-header-cell h-8 whitespace-pre-wrap align-middle text-left MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-1bz4y89" 
                scope="col" 
                style="width: 50%;">
                Target Text
            </th>
            <th class="MuiTableCell-root table-header-cell h-8 whitespace-pre-wrap align-middle text-left MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-1bz4y89" 
                scope="col" 
                style="width: 50%;">
                Finding
            </th>
            <th class="MuiTableCell-root table-header-cell h-8 whitespace-pre-wrap align-middle text-left w-13 MuiTableCell-head MuiTableCell-sizeMedium css-1bz4y89" 
                scope="col">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        // Wait for DOM to be fully loaded
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const targetTextElement = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('th'))
                .find(th => th.textContent.trim() === 'Target Text');
            
            console.log(targetTextElement);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Here you have the console log:

Make sure the <tr> is inside a <table>, If not, it will return undefined
