# Select all elements that contain the specified text in a SVG tag

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, dom

I would like to select all elements that contain a specified text in a SVG tag.

Something like this

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].filter(e => e.childNodes && [...e.childNodes].find(n => n.nodeValue?.match("something")))
```

Or an other response of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799236)

How can I select this text element by its containing text?

```html
<body>
  <svg>
    <g>
      <text>something</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[...document.querySelectorAll("*")]` approach needs to parse the `nodeValue` of **every** element.
All the work is done by the (slower) JavaScript Engine.

Instead, you can use the [**TreeWalker API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to go look for `TextNodes` only.
Now the work is done by the (faster) Browser Engine.

**IE9** was the last Browser to implement the TreeWalker API, so this solution has been around for at least 10 years now...
(*but for some reason people still prefer the slow jQuery contains or a-like solutions*)

[**TreeWalker API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)

- `#Text` Nodes are nodeType **4**
  and remember whitespace (space,return,tab) between Nodes are TextNodes
- Be aware nodeNames in the HTML NameSpace are **UPPERCASE**;
  but nodeNames in de SVG NameSpace are **lowercase**

```html
<body>
  <svg something>
    <g id=somethingelse>
      <text id=ONE>something</text>
      <text id=TWO>nothing</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
<script>
  function findNodes(
    str = '', 
    root = document.body
  ) {
    let tree = document.createTreeWalker(root, 4);
    let nodes = [];
    let node;
    while (node = tree.nextNode()) {
      if (node.parentNode.nodeName === "text" 
          && 
          node.data.includes(str)) {
        nodes.push(node);
      }
    }
    console.log('Find:', str)
    nodes.map((text, idx, arr) => {
      console.log(`${idx+1}/${arr.length} `, text.data, ' in:', text.parentNode.id);
    });
    return nodes;
  }
  findNodes('something');
  findNodes('thing');
</script>
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm using a dom parser that doesn't support this API yet so I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/issues/35) but for now I can't use your answer, do you know an other way of doing this?

Comment: See the answers you linked to, proces the nodevalue of every node

Comment: These answers don't works for me, it just don't detect any nodes inside a SVG node

Comment: What is your SVG? Are you doing this in the Browser or SSR?