# Is there a way to get a website element by the visible text?

Tags: javascript, html

I am just starting to learn some basics of javascript related to html. I would like to know is there a way to select the html element by its visible text?

For example:
If I would like to click the “Interesting” button on the stackfoverflow page I can find the element by querySelector.

stack overflow html page code sample:

```html
<a class="youarehere is-selected flex--item s-btn s-btn__muted s-btn__outlined" 
    href="?tab=interesting" 
    data-nav-xhref="" 
    title="Questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preference" 
    data-value="interesting" data-shortcut="">
        Interesting
</a>
```

one way of locate the html element:

```js
document.querySelector("a[class='youarehere is-selected flex--item s-btn s-btn__muted s-btn__outlined']").click()
```

I know there might be some other ways to locate the element, but am I able to locate the element by the visable text “Interesting”? Thanks if anyone knows how.

stack overflow page html sample image down below.

[stack overflow html sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2WWH.png)

Comment: Yes but it would require querying every element for it's innerText. This is not native and will comparatively slow. This may also match elements that wrap the desired element too.

Comment: If it's just the text content you want to match, then you are stuck checking every element, as @phuzi mentioned. The only way to cut this down is by reducing the search area to only child elements of a container, or to scan only elements of a certain type (e.g. anchor tags, elements with a given class name, etc.).

Comment: Check this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799291/11286971 I think this will inspire you

Comment: Also, it's a bad practice query elements `class` attribute, because if anything in the class changed (i.e. order of classes), your query will fail. You should query it like `a.youarehere.is-selected.flex--item` instead. Another trick is to find something unique in it's parent elements, and query by that, i.e in this particular case: `#mainbar div.s-btn-group>a[data-value="intersting"]`

Comment: Thanks for the information provided. Appreciated.