# Running user scripts without Tamper Monkey

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I have been experimenting with Tampermonkey and making scripts to change web elements. I ran the following user script in Tamper Monkey :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       "job changer"
// @namespace  Marshmellows
// @version    0.1
// @description  Change 'Jobs' in stackoverflow to Hello!
// @match      http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @copyright  
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('nav-jobs').innerHTML = 'Hello!';
});
```

This js did what it was supposed by using Tamper Monkey.
[image: The js file that I am using for this particular extension.]
However, if I manually install this js as an extension for chrome, the script no longer works. 
[image: The extension was installed but does not work.]
Can somebody please offer than guidance for this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either avoid using `@require` as it's [not supported natively](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) and write in [vanilla JavaScript](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       "job changer"
// @namespace  Marshmellows
// @version    0.1
// @description  Change 'Jobs' in stackoverflow to Hello!
// @match      https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant      none
// @run-at     document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('nav-jobs').innerHTML = 'Hello!';
}, false);
```

Or add jQuery directly inside the code:
[How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey scripts in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome)