# greasemonkey script to select radio button

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

i'm new here. i've a question related to greasemonkey.

A page  contain multiple radio buttoned values and one choice is to made, this correct choice option  is hidden within the page

the radio buttons are present in the form whose structure is

```
<form name="bloogs" action="/myaddres.php" id="bloogs" method="post" >
```

then the hidden field as

```
<input type=hidden value="abcd" name="ans">
```

then all the radio button values are followed as

```
<input  type="radio" id="r1" name="opt" value="abcd"> abcd
<input  type="radio" id="r2" name="opt" value="efgh"> efgh
<input  type="radio" id="r3" name="opt" value="ijkl"> ijkl
```

and so on

thus i need the button with value=abcd be 'checked' as soon as the page loads. Thanks

Comment: any extra information comment here.. i'll try to post it,thanks.

Comment: Cant you do like: `<input  type="radio" id="r1" name="opt" value="abcd" selected="selected" /> abcd`

Comment: None of the answers were effective. The values keeps on changing on every page. i need to exrtact the value from hidden field and now select the radio button corresponding to it

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID, IDs **must** be unique within the same document.

Comment: ya you are right. i've written it once and copy pasted it and forgot to change the id.

Comment: Anybody knowing javascript or greasemonkey please try it.. Update or put in your implementation.. Plz..

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways you can use:

**1** You can pre-select it by putting in `selected="selected"` like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" name="opt" value="abcd" checked="checked" /> abcd
```

**2** You can use **[jQuery](http://jquery.org)** to do it easily (I don't know whether it will be applicable in terms of greasmonky though)

```
$(function(){
  $('input[value="abcd"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

**3** You can loop through all elements and selected the one with raw javascript

```
var form = document.getElementById('bloogs');

for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++)
{
  if (form.elements[i].type == 'radio')
  {
    if (form.elements[i].value == 'abcd')
    {
      form.elements[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

This uses jquery and selects a radio after reading the value from hidden field:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[value="' + $('#hidden_field_id').val() + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Or with raw javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('bloogs');
var hidden_value = document.getElementById('hidden_field_id').value;

for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++)
{
  if (form.elements[i].type == 'radio')
  {
    if (form.elements[i].value == hidden_value)
    {
      form.elements[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 2:**

As per the name, here is how you can go about:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[value="' + $('input[name="ans"]').val() + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: I dont know jscript. also need the code to work in greasemonkey. I suppose gm supports only javascript code.

Comment: @muqtar: yes js (jquery) is supported by gm.

Comment: ok. but as i said the value changes in every new page so putting value=abcd doesn't work. as i said that the value from hidden feild has to be extracted then the radio button corresponding to it has to be checked.

Comment: To select radio button you have to add `checked` attribute, not `selected`

Comment: @OP: Yes, GreaseMonkey scripts are written in Javascript (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#Technical_details). jQuery is not Javascript, it's a Javascript *library* that makes some things more convenient. It is *possible* to use jQuery in a GreaseMonkey script, but you have to make a special effort to do so (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey).

Comment: @muqtar: See my @OP comment above (flagging it up this because "@OP" isn't going to trigger the automatic notification, but "@muqtar" will -- not enough coffee this morning)

Comment: @sarfraz: the input field does not have any id as you have mentioned 'hidden_field_id' in the code. i've mentioned the hidden input tag. The code doesn't work after i run in gm.Thanks.

Comment: Anybody knowing javascript or greasemonkey please try it.. Update or put in your implementation.. Plz..

Comment: @muqtar: what is common in your hidden field, does it have the same name?

Comment: yes the name is always "ans" and the value keeps changing in every new page.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done greasemonkey, but this may help:

use jQuery and do

```
$('[value="abcd"]').click()
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use jQuery with GreaseMonkey you're going to have to get good at writing delayed and try / retry type code.  You need to start with something like this:

```
var _s1 = document.createElement('script');
_s1.src = 'http://www.ghostdev.com/jslib/jquery-1.3.2.js';
_s1.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_s1);
```

That loads jQuery into your page.  Next, you set something up that operates like so:

```
function dojQueryStuff() {
  if (jQuery == undefined) {
    setTimeout(dojQueryStuff, 1000);
  } else {
    // In here is where all of my code goes that uses jQuery.
  }
}

dojQueryStuff();
```

You've defined a function that'll check for jQuery's presence, and if it doesn't find it try again 1 second later.  That gives the script time to load.  Please note, if you don't use your own copy of jQuery the one listed in my example does not provide a $ variable.  At the end of the script I have `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`, so you'll access the jQuery functionality via `$j` or `jQuery`.

Comment: this is no longer necessary with current versions of greasemonkey - you can now use @require to load libraries when your script is installed.

Comment: Cant understand the jquery at all.. either put in the entire jscript greasemonkey code or in javascript gm code. Thaks