# Beginner : How to remove a node that contains a specific class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have a list that every bock is constructed like below. Some of the blocks have a `<span class="protected-icon"></span>`. 
I would like to make a really simple greasemonkey plugin that removes that block. 
So, my question is using Javascript how can I remove/hide `the entire block` ( `<div data-item-type="user" class="js-stream-item stream-item"></div>`that contains it?

```
<div data-item-type="user" class="js-stream-item stream-item">
<div class="user-content-rest">
    <span class="user-name">
         <span class="protected-icon"></span>
      </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: with *entire block* do you mean the `user-name` div ? the `user-content-rest` div or the `stream-item` one ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli sorry for this,  I mean this `stream-item`

Comment: ok .. my answer assumed you wanted that one :)

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution to your problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide you can use the [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) method.
To remove you can use the [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) method.

Now to target the block you want

```
// change hide to remove for complete removal from the DOM.
$('.stream-item:has(.protected-icon)').hide();
```

will hide all the divs with class `stream-item` that contain an element with class `protected-icon`
**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eeuQd/

---

**Update**

Here is a reference on using jQuery with greasemonkey [How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey)

I read that you are trying to use this with twitter page. Twitter is using Ajax requests to load parts of the page (*and load new tweets..*) so you might need to use an interval to your script that that it gets re-applied periodically..

That is because your code might run before the twitter has actually loaded the tweets in the page..

something like

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.stream-item:has(.protected-icon)').hide();
}, 2000 ); // 2000 means every two seconds (in milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 5):

How to do it without jQuery:

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('protected-icon');
for (var i=p.length; --i>=0;) {
    p[i].parentNode.removeChild(p[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sRs4s/1/

**UPDATE** If you want to remove the entire `stream-item` block, you have to loop up to it:

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('protected-icon');
var cstr = "stream-item";
for (var i=p.length; --i>=0;) {
    var n = p[i];
    while(n.className.split(" ").indexOf(cstr)==-1) { // won't work in older browsers
        n = n.parentNode;
    }
    n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sRs4s/3/

See [Best way to find if an item is in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/143847/901048) if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: Nice one, one addition though. How can I remove the entire node? `<div data-item-type="user" class="js-stream-item stream-item"></div>`

Comment: I have updated your fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/sRs4s/2/ with the exact div. I would be very appreciated for this.

Comment: I can't understand. Even though this is working http://jsfiddle.net/sRs4s/6/ and also the jquery version on my local web server using Grease Monkey, it can not work on twitter page. Why is that ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos Afraid I can't help you with that from here.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$('protected-icon').closest('div[data-item-type="user"]').remove();
```

You could also hide the element for later use:

```
$('protected-icon').closest('div[data-item-type="user"]').hide();
```

Comment: But I want to remove the entire <div></div>

Comment: I don't think you want `closest()` here. The documentation says it only returns 0 or 1 item. If you want to remove ALL the <div> tags, I don't think this would do it.

Comment: @Zero21xxx, maybe I don't understand the requirement. Who said anything about all the div tags? The OP seems to indicate that he wants the div that contains `protected-icon` to be removed.

Comment: I can't understand. Even though this is working on my local web server using Grease Monkey, it can not work on twitter page. Why is that ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos, What do you mean it's not working? Do you get an error? Does the page in question include jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Greasemonkey but I noticed you tagged this as jQuery, so I'm assuming you would get use out of a jQuery script.

I would do this **in case you want to bring it back at some point**:

```
$('.protected-icon').parents('.js-stream-item.stream-item[data-item-type=user]').css({'display':'none'});
```

Comment: I can't understand. Even though this is working on my local web server using Grease Monkey, it can not work on twitter page. Why is that ?

Comment: Hey Kaoukkos, I set up a jsfiddle for you to look at. http://jsfiddle.net/2nHKj/. If the problem persists, try isolating this script from any other script blocks, and continue debugging from there.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple using jQuery. Add the following in the top area of your greasemonkey script:

```
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
```

Then use the following jQuery:

```
$('span.protected-icon').parents('.js-stream-item').hide();
```

Update: Sorry, I had a typo. parent should have been parents.

Comment: I can't understand. Even though this is working on my local web server using Grease Monkey, it can not work on twitter page. Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery you could do the this to hide the block:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.protected-icon').hide();
 });
```

Or to remove it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('span.protected-icon').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the question asked here, which is a different question but contains the answer :-)

[Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

edit: assuming you mean pure javascript, if you are using jQuery see all the other answers!

Comment: I can't understand. Even though this is working on my local web server using Grease Monkey, it can not work on twitter page. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('span.protected-icon').parents('.user-content-rest').remove();
```

That will find all the spans with the `protected-icon` class, then traverse the DOM tree until an element with the `user-content-rest` is encountered and remove that object.

Comment: I can't understand. Even though this is working on my local web server using Grease Monkey, it can not work on twitter page. Why is that ?

Comment: Then there is a difference between your local web page and Twitter or you're not loading the jQuery library correctly when you're not pointing at your local server.