# How do I get jQuery to work with a Greasemonkey 0.8 script (On Firefox 2), with no internet to the PC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, firefox2

I'm using **Firefox 2.0.0.11** and **Greasemonkey 0.8.x** and the latest **jQuery version (1.3.2)** that works with Greasemonkey 0.8.
I try to load this Userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        TEST
// @include     *
// @require     jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('jQuery!');
});
```

but I receive the error:

```
Error: $ is not defined
Source File: file:///G:/Firefox/Data/profile/gm_scripts/huhu/huhu.user.js
Line: 8
```

I know that I have to update this old browser. But it's not possible. I have to work with that!

I want to load jQuery code on a local PC with no internet connection.
I have copied jquery.min.js in the same folder where the userscript is.

```
G:/Firefox/Data/profile/gm_scripts/huhu/jquery.min.js
```

Any ideas where the problem is?

Regards, Bernte

Comment: That means jQuery wasn't loaded before your script. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey

Comment: "... the *latest* jQuery (1.3.2)...," say again!?

Comment: @Alexander jQuery (1.3.2) version that works with Greasemonkey 0.8 :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to install a Greasemonkey script, from a local drive, such that jQuery will work.
But, first, here are the...

#### Prerequisites common to both methods:

1. Older versions of Greasemonkey (and Firefox) got confused easily.  So, use Greasemonkey's *Script Manager* to uninstall any old versions of the script.
2. Go to the `gm_scripts` folder, in your [Profile Folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox), and physically delete the folder for your script, if it's present.
3. Make sure your script source-code is in a file with a `user.js` extension.  EG: `Hello World.user.js`
4. Make sure your script source-code is in a folder that is **not in a system `TMP` or `temp` folder**.  For example, place the source file in `C:\My GM scripts\`.
5. Likewise, this is not, and do not use, any folder in the [Firefox Profile Folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox) tree.
6. When in doubt, or if things appear "flaky", restart Firefox.

#### Method 1, the computer has internet access:

1. Merely point the `@require` at Google's copy of the correct jQuery version.  For GM 0.8, it should be no later than jQuery 1.3.2.

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name     Hiya Ma
   // @include  http://stackoverflow.com/*
   // @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
   // ==/UserScript==

   $("body").prepend ('<div>Hello world!</div>');
   ```
2. Use the Firefox, *Open File* menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) to open the source file. (EG: `C:\My GM scripts\Hello World.user.js`)

   **Or:**
   Drag-and-drop the source file to any open Firefox tab.
3. Greasemonkey will prompt to install the script. Follow the prompts.

#### Method 2, the computer cannot access the web:

1. Download the appropriate jQuery version (1.3.2 in this case), and save it as `jquery.min.js`, in **the same folder** as the script source (`C:\My GM scripts\`, in this example).
2. Do not use any path in the `@require` directive:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name     Hiya Ma
   // @include  http://stackoverflow.com/*
   // @require  jquery.min.js
   // ==/UserScript==

   $("body").prepend ('<div>Hello world!</div>');
   ```
3. Install the script as in steps 2 and 3 of *Method 1*.  You do not need to open or drag the jQuery file.

---

#### Also Note:

1. `G:/Firefox/Data/profile/gm_scripts/huhu/jquery.min.js` look like a Firefox profile directory.  You place no files here.  Greasemonkey will copy and rename files as appropriate.
2. `@grant` is not supported until Greasemonkey version 1.0.  Do not use it here.
3. `$(document).ready()` is not needed here, nor in most GM scripts.  Greasemonkey fires at the correct time by default.
4. These methods ***were verified*** against Firefox 2.0.0.20 and Greasemonkey 0.8.20100408.6, but they pretty much apply to all versions of FF+GM until GM 1.0.

---

#### What to do if you get an `NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED` error:

This error was not uncommon with older versions of Greasemonkey.  The two most frequent causes were poor `temp`-file housekeeping (by FF/GM) and Firefox profile corruption.

Do the following to remedy this in most cases:

1. Repeat the prerequisites, listed above.
2. Purge the system temp folder(s) of anything that resembles the script source file, or any `@require`d files, or any `@resource`d files.

   In this example, look for `hiya_ma.user.js` and `jquerymin.js`, in particular.

   In Windows, the temp folder(s) have the address(es): `%TMP%` and `%TEMP%`.
3. In the `gm_scripts` folder, make sure that `config.xml` has no references to deleted or missing scripts.  If there are no (other) scripts, delete `config.xml`.
4. If all else fails, uses Firefox's *Profile Manager* to create a new profile and reinstall your scripts there.

Comment: hi brock.. i used your method 2. i created a folder C:\userscripts\ where i copied jquery.min.js (1.32) and Hiya Ma.user.js inside. i uninstalled all userscripts in greasemonkey and restarted firefox 2.0.0.11. then i dragged&dropped Hiya Ma.user.js inside the firefox window! after press install i recieve the following error http://tinyurl.com/96wksag  i think that firefox 2.0.0.11 does not handle that, right?

Comment: i tried it with 2.0.0.20 as you described it! and it works!! seems to give problems with 2.0.0.11

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that the problem is between 2.0.0.11 and 2.0.0.20.  That error looks like what used to happen sometimes with FF/GM.  It only worked with 2.0.0.20 because that had the side effect of changing or refreshing the FF profile. See the new section in the answer.