# GreaseMonkey doesn't execute a script with functions from GM_* family

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I decided to add a memory to my GM script. I added a single call to GM_setValue and suddenly script stopped to be called at all. I tried adding @grant line to the metadata block, tried reinstalling and renaming the script - no luck.

Moreover, commenting the lines with GM_* functions doesn't help. They must be deleted in order to script become functional again. Even mentioning them in @grant line without actually calling prevents script from starting.

I'm experiencing this on Ubuntu-12.04, Firefox-19.0.2 and GreaseMonkey-1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [no bugs logged for this kind of problem](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues).  **You need to show your script** or [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

What errors do you see on the error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)?

What may be happening is that your script is using page-scope objects, taking advantage of Greasemonkey's bizarre new sandbox disabling.  When a script attempts to use a `GM_` function, or sets a `@grant` value (other than `none`), the sandbox is switched back on as a side-effect.  So, if your script was using page-scope objects, it will now throw errors.

Comment: Thanks, Brock! You're right. I made use of $(document).ready() handler in my script. It was perfectly working if gm script has no granted privileges. There is a related question, btw:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey

Comment: That question may not apply here as much as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12146445/331508).  Is your script working now?  If not, open a new question and show the code.

Comment: yeah. All works now. The problem was indeed GM silently switching modes of operation depending on requested privileges.