# How can i select the correct radio button with greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to create a script that would select the correct option automatically

Here is what I have so far

http://jsfiddle.net/VqQaN/58/

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); //get the li
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) { //loop through the li
    if (labels[i].textContent == "misafir getirebilir") { //check li text
        labels[i].click(); //if correct text, click the li
    }
}

console.log ("answerTxt: ", labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery for that:
[How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey)

While using something like this:
[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: i don't know enough javascript and jquery so i can't do it.. thanks for your  helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); //get the li
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) { //loop through the li
    if (labels[i].textContent == "1 misafir getirebilir") { //check li text
        labels[i].querySelector('input').click(); //if correct text, click the li
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iZUTIX/1/edit)

Comment: excellent thanks.. please Can you look it ? http://jsfiddle.net/VqQaN/60/ and do you have facebook account ? I want to follow you...

Comment: @Halil İbrahim Tekmenüray [Modified Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rMvHK/). If you are satisfied with my answer, mark it as accepted. If you have further doubts, please open another question rather than comment below my answer.

Comment: Thanks.. i don't understand , that code is working on jsfdlle but not work on greasemonkey :/ why ?

Comment: I probably solved problem UTF-8 :) thxx

Comment: Do you have a facebook ? please say me..