# require jQuery in a user.js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, userscripts

I am trying to load jQuery using `@require` so I can start writing the user script.  The script is failing on the first `$`.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

How do I load jQuery in a user script?

I have seen [other examples on github](https://github.com/Cyb3rsoft/facebook.user.js/blob/master/facebook.tamper.js) and they make it look easy.  What am I missing?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Test
// @description    Test description
// @license        MIT License
// @charset        UTF-8
// @version        0.1
// @match          http://example.com/* 
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(function() {

    console.log('ok, lets start'); 

});
```

Comment: Just start running commands do not do $(function() if its a userscript it gets called at a certain time. You do not have that much control of when it gets ran.

Comment: [userjs] is for *Opera* but you appear to be running Chrome. Which is it?

Comment: Chrome, isn't all `user.js` scripts meant to run on both?

Comment: No, the cross-browser tag is [userscripts]. and `*.user.js` files are not often portable between the browsers or even between Chrome and Chrome + Tampermonkey (which is what you should use, on Chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using chrome to run your user scripts, you have to opt for an alternative method as `@require` is not supported by chrome.

> Chromium does not support @require, @resource, unsafeWindow, GM_registerMenuCommand, GM_setValue, or GM_getValue.
>
> [The Chromium Project - User scripts](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts)

More details on:

- [How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey scripts in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome)
- [How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey/23948066)

Comment: This answer and [that linked page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) are partially obsolete. `unsafeWindow` is now provided by Chrome (but is otherwise useless on that platform sans Tampermonkey). `GM_xmlhttpRequest` also does now support cross-domain requests.