# Greasemonkey: click a link

Tags: greasemonkey

I would like to click on this link using Greasemonkey:

```
<a class="bbbx-button bbbx-button-grey" id="vote-button" data-bbbx-trigger="module.vote.submit" data-bbbx-id="51526" data-bbbx-score="10" data-bbbx-vote-type="up"><img src="//du3rc6beq6sv9.cloudfront.net/release1406643004647-5-1-2-1/assets/skins/default/images/vote/heart.png"> vote! <small id="vote-count">( 14 )</small></a>
```

I tried this code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   test
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
console.log("Start");


window.setTimeout(start, 7000);

function start()
{
    $("a#vote-button")[0].click();

    console.log("End clicktime");
}
```

But unfortunately I can't find the problem.

Comment: Your current code does work as expected in my test case. What is the full console output?

Comment: Please try at http://bit.ly/1uH4QUP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have jQuery loaded in your GM script.

Add this:

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
```

Feel free to change the version.

Have a look at this question, it also provides some solutions for websites that already have jQuery loaded: [How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey?rq=1)

Comment: I did an edit. But the End clicktime log doesn't appear too now.

Comment: Could you please have a look at it again?

Comment: I am not sure what else can you do. Can you please check if jQuery is avaiable?