# Click simulating troubles

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, onclick, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write some comment expander (as greasemonkey script) for livejournal, and get stuck with click simulating on the expand link:

```
<div style='margin-top: 3px; font-size: smaller'>
 (<a href="http://unique page url" rel="nofollow">Reply</a>) 
 (<a href='page url'>Parent</a>) 
 (<a href='http://unique page url'>Thread</a>) 
 <span id='expand_*'>(<a href='http://unique page url' onclick="ExpanderEx.make(event,this,'http://unique page url','*',true)">Expand</a>)</span>
    <div class="quickreply" id="ljqrt*" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this code to activate all links on the page, but failed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
   $(this).[0].click();
  });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, because I'm totally newbie with jquery.

UPD.
I modify script, so it looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
 console.log("function execute"); 
 $('[id^="expand_"] a').click(); 
 console.log("function Log");
 console.log($()); 
});
```

Console output in firebug after execution is:

```
function execute  --- lj_expa...user.js (line 10) 
TypeError: $(...) is null --- lj_expa...user.js (line 11) 
Server did not return the new auth_token, further request may fail Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString' --- ??.ljli...3140103 (line 1372)
```

**UPD. Adding the line below solved my problem, both selectors work correct!**

`// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: What do you mean by "activate all links"?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Simply click on links, that are selected by $('a')

Comment: Why would you want to click on all links. Surely you want to click on just one.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I try to explain. Livejournal is a blogging platform, that uses conversation threading for commentary. If the count of replies to entry reaches (don't remember exact value) 50, then I can't see all replies, only a top of answer hierarchy, until use expand script. Because I often read such posts, an idea comes over my mind - to write a script, that activates expand links, after I load a page.

Comment: So this is a Greasemonkey script?

Comment: Yes, my fault, I completely forgot to mention this.

Comment: It's slightly confusing in that the HTML in the question appears to be some sort of template. I'm guessing that `<span id='expand_*'>` gets translated into something else, possibly `<span class='expand'>`. If you "right-click > inspect element", you can see how the Expand links end up. Let me know what it is.

Comment: HTML in the question is a part of the page's code, that i get with "inspect element". I checked the possibility, that you mentioned here,  and don't see any tracks. I can duplicate the code, and as I understand it ends up with unique number of thread:
`<span id="expand_34400795"> 
<a href="http://*.livejournal.com/1021211.html?thread=34400795#t34400795" onclick="ExpanderEx.make(event,this,'http://*.livejournal.com/1021211.html?thread=34400795#t34400795','34400795',true)">Expand</a></span>`

Comment: Excellent, that tells me what I need to know. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on expand links of the following structure :

```
<span id="expand_34400795"> <a href="http://*.livejournal.com/1021211.html?thread=34400795#t34400795" onclick="ExpanderEx.make(event,this,'http://*.livejournal.com/1021211.html?threa??d=34400795#t34400795','34400795',true)">Expand</a></span>
```

try :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="expand_"] a').click();
});
```

In plain English, this jQuery statement reads `find all <a> elements in <span>s with ids starting 'expand_', then click the links`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried it, but debugger shows me an error `Cannot read property 'click' of null`. jQuery is loaded on page:
command `typeof jQuery` gets output `function`.

Comment: I have tried selecting not <span>, but an href with an attribute click: `$('a[onclick*="ExpanderEx"]').click();` - and got same error

Comment: Mmm, very strange because even if the selector selects nothing, an empty jQuery collection will be returned, not null. What does `console.log($());` give?

Comment: What do you get from `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($().jquery);
 });` ?

Comment: Without any selector I get `TypeError: $(...) is undefined`, with `$('[id^="expand_"] a').click();` - `TypeError: $(...) is null`

Comment: @Anubelora, I think these error conditions are to do with using jQuery in Greasmonkey - an area in which I'm not expert. **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey)** seems like a good place to start.