# How do I select an option with Javascript in a dropdown that doesn't have an element ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, dropdown

I have a website that I cannot edit that I visit frequently. I'm using Both Greasemonkey for Firefox and Tampermonkey for Chrome to try to use Javascript to automatically select a value in a dropdown. Below is the element of the dropdown.

```
<select name="term">
    <option value="12">12 /mo. - $20.95/mo.</option>
    <option value="24">24 /mo. - $17.95/mo.</option>
    <option value="36">36 /mo. - $15.95/mo.</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, there is no element id. I've tried following the answers on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript) but changed them to use `document.getElementsByName` instead of `document.getElementById` since this dropdown element doesn't have an id but nothing I've done has worked.

How can I use Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey to automatically select the value of "36" whenever I visit that webpage?

Answer (score 3):

You can access an element by name with an attribute selector. When you set its value, that selects the option with that value.

```js
$("select[name=term]").val("36");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="term">
    <option value="12">12 /mo. - $20.95/mo.</option>
    <option value="24">24 /mo. - $17.95/mo.</option>
    <option value="36">36 /mo. - $15.95/mo.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't do anything. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does it make a difference if there is more than one dropdown on this webpage with basically the same elements and values?

Comment: This will update all of the dropdowns with `name="term"`

Comment: Added an execuable snippet to show that it works. I don't know if doing it from GreaseMonkey makes a difference, though.

Comment: So I did what the person below suggested (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32979483/5309708): `// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js`

`// ==/UserScript==`

`$("select[name=term]").val("36");`

But it didn't work.

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know what changes when running code in GreaseMonkey or TamperMonkey.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979378
// @match        http://website.with.dropdown.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(document.querySelector && document.querySelector('select[name="term"]') || []).value = '36';
```

```html
<select name="term">
  <option value="12">12 /mo. - $20.95/mo.</option>
  <option value="24">24 /mo. - $17.95/mo.</option>
  <option value="36">36 /mo. - $15.95/mo.</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use jQuery in greasemonkey with

```
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
```

[How can I use jQuery in Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey)

then the jQuery selector would be along the lines of:

```
$("select[name=term]")
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't do anything. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does it make a difference if there is more than one dropdown on this webpage with basically the same elements and values?