# Userscript to bypass same-origin policy for accessing nested iframes

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, same-origin-policy

In the following HTML mockup, the nested iframes are originating from different subdomains. This is causing messages such as **error: Permission denied to access property "document"**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe id="outer_iframe_1" src="https://subdomain1.example.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe id="outer_iframe_2" src="https://subdomain2.example.com">
        <div>
            <iframe id="inner_iframe_2" src="https://subdomain4.example.com"></iframe>
        </div>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe id="outer_iframe_3" src="https://subdomain3.example.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am intending to fetch and modify values within the nested iframes (eg. `inner_frame_2`) with a Userscript, so bypassing the Same-origin policy should be possible. But examples of `GM_xmlhttpRequest` seem to rely on GET/POST requests, whereas I only want to deal with the already loaded page data within these iframes.

Am I misunderstanding `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, or is there another approach I should be taking here?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the content (scripts) of the iframes? Or do you want to control alien sites remotely?

Comment: @NilsRückmann Not sure I understand the question, but I don't have any control over the actual site's code. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the only way you can do it, is by using the [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method to send messages with data from iframes to the top window. To catch each iframe inside Greasemonkey script see [Brock Adams answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37624206/1889685) on [Apply a Greasemonkey userscript to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616818/apply-a-greasemonkey-userscript-to-an-iframe); you'll have to use the GM [`@match`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match) directive like this:

```
// @match        http://subdomain1.example.com/*
```

or

```
// @match        *.example.com/*
```

Then you can check if the current window is the top window, and/or check the `document.domain` to identify the iframe:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @match        http://main-domain.something
// @match        *.example.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    if (window.top === window.self) {
        // Here we are at the top window and we setup our message event listener
    }
    else {
        // Here we get inside the iframes.
        // We can address and check each iframe url with document.domain
    }
})();
```

We need to hook an event for `"message"` to the top window that will handle each message it receives from the iframes with the data:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // do something with the event.data
}, false);
```

And we can identify the iframes by using `document.domain`; do whatever manipulation we need to the iframe elements; retrieve all the data we want and send the message to the top window:

```
window.top.postMessage({
    // data object we send to the top window
}, "*");
```

I created a demo to try this and it works pretty well. My top window URL is `http://zikro.gr/dbg/gm/iframes/main.php` and the subdomains are like `http://subdomain1.zikro.gr/`. The top window HTML is identical to yours with my iframe urls and the GM script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://zikro.gr/dbg/gm/iframes/main.php
// @match        *.zikro.gr/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    if (window.top === window.self) {
        // Here we are at the top window and we setup our message event listener
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f00"; // Just a UI change to identify the top window
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            window.console.log("This is data from '" + event.data.title +
                               "'; with message '" + event.data.message +
                               "'; with data '" + event.data.data +"'" +
                               "'; from domain '" + event.data.domain + "'");
        }, false);
    }
    else {
        // Here we get inside the iframes.
        // We can address and check each iframe url with document.domain

        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0f0"; // Just a UI change to identify the iframe window

        // We change something inside the iframe
        var dataDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        dataDiv.innerHTML += " with a change!";

        // And we post a message to the top window with all the data we want inside an object
        window.top.postMessage({
            title: document.title,
            domain: document.domain,
            message: "Hello from, iframe - " + document.title,
            data: dataDiv.innerText
        }, "*");
    }

})();
```

And a screen capture for those who don't have Greasemonkey/Tampermoney installed to test this:

[image: Script in action]

**PS:** It's not valid to add elements directly inside an iframe tag like this:

```
<iframe id="outer_iframe_2" src="https://subdomain2.example.com">
<div>
    <iframe id="inner_iframe_2" src="https://subdomain4.example.com"></iframe>
</div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Your example page is not working anymore, maybe because the top page is forced to `https` and the iframes have a `http` address. BTW I found at least 3 copies over the internet, before I found your original reply ;-)

Comment: @close There are no subdomains because I've moved the server and I didn't get to backup these. I'll try to fix it or delete the whole demo section.

Comment: I still have trouble to fathom why you are forced to use such an extreme amount of bloat to do such a simple and common thing.

Comment: @Akito you are welcome to write your own answer and enlight us all regarding making things simple. Please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but this is for those who want to use javascript to manipulate a webpage for data processing purposes.

Softwares like PhantomJS are designed for "browser automation" and allow removing the cross origin policy altogether.

```
phantomjs.exe --web-security=no script.js
```

Inside your script, you can use

```
page.open("http://fiddle.jshell.net/9aQv5/show/", function(status) { // Load a webpage
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js", function() { // Add support jor jQuery
        page.evaluate(function() { // Run custom script
            console.log($("body").find("iframe").attr("src"));

            console.log($("body").find("iframe").contents().find("iframe").attr("src"));

            console.log($("body").find("iframe").contents().find("iframe").contents().find("#about-puppy-linux").html());
        });
        phantom.exit(0);
    });
});
```

You get the following output:

```
//fiddle.jshell.net/9aQv5/show/light/
http://www.puppylinux.com/
About Puppy Linux
```

Comment: I take it this only removes the security for your particular userscript (which you have to trust anyway)? Still, the `window.postMessage()` method seems more portable, as it doesn't require the userscript host to circumvent the policy.