# Is there a way to change "global execution context" programmatically inside a userscript in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have a userscript where I'm using Tampermonkey to change a DOM element's text. This code

```
$(".widget-container_cimta_revenue_kpi_number").find('div.count')
                                               .text('$50,000')
                                               .css('fontSize', 24);
```

works fine in Chrome Dev Tools > Console Log as long as I set the "execution context" manually in the dropdown from "top" to "waveApexPage". [see dropdown value for execution context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJqvd.png)

Is there a way to programmatically change the execution context value in this dropdown inside chrome dev tool? I believe it is the global execution context?

Comment: (Probably you can't.) Instead you should modify the `@include` or `@match` URL to match the href attribute of the iframe you intend to target.

Comment: Thanks Nisarg. Was suspecting that was the case.. However, when I view source, I do not see any references to iframe. Is there an example where I can target a specific div class with @include or @match?

Comment: That `waveApexPage` you see should be an iframe element. You should be able to find it via the elements panel. It's possible that it is added via Javascript at a later stage, so it might not appear in the source you are looking at.

Comment: I see the iframe waveApexPage now.  Do you have an example of how I can target that with @include? I see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616818/apply-a-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-userscript-to-an-iframe but doesn't look like what I want...

Comment: Now you are matching with the href value of that iframe. If you want to omit some part of it, you can use `@include` and then put `*` in the part that you intend to omit. It should be straightforward.