# Userscript does not execute in Facebook "Like" iframe

Tags: iframe, facebook-like, userscripts, tampermonkey

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616818/apply-a-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-userscript-to-an-iframe), I should be able to get a userscript to work in an iframe simply by specifying a match URL. However, it does not work for me in case of the iframe for Facebook like button embedded on - say - `codeforces.com`.

As an MVCE, here's a small script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Bug test
// @version      0.1
// @author       Gaurang Tandon
// @match        https://codeforces.com/*
// @match        https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/like.php
// @match        https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/like.php/
// @match        https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/like.php/*

// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    console.log(window.location.hostname);
}();
```

Loading this on codeforces.com gives only one log statement in DevTools Console and that is `codeforces.com`. Removing one or two of those `@match` directives changes nothing.

Why does the script not run in that iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **that MCVE has a couple of problems**:

1. The `@match` needs to be:

   ```
   // @match  https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/like.php*
   ```

   because the typical URL is like: `www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/like.php?app_id...`
2. There is a syntax error on the last line.  It was `}();`  It needs to be `} ) ();`
   You would have seen that if you looked in the console or used *Developer* -> *Run syntax check* from the Tampermonkey editor menu.

Next, **Tampermonkey tries to protect you** from such foolishness **by default blacklisting certain sites**.
In the case of Facebook:

1. Facebook spams their widgets, scripts, images, iframes everywhere. If a script ran on each instance it could degrade the performance of many a site. (Personally, use tools like uMatrix and uBlock to completely shut down Facebook and similar sites.)
2. Facebook widgets are a prime target for malicious scripters. So, since there is seldom a legit reason to script those, Tampermonkey tries to block those by default.

You can **see what Tampermonkey tries to block** by:

1. Go to Tampermonkey settings.
2. Set *Config mode* to either "Beginner" or "Advanced":
   [image: mode setting]
3. Scroll down to "*Security*".
4. In the *Blacklisted Pages* box, you may see lines like:

   ```
   *://www.facebook.com/plugins/*
   *://www.facebook.com/*/plugins/*
   ```
5. Remove the line that stops the execution you want, and press the *Save* button for that text box.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the syntax error. It occurred just as I was shortening my existing code and somehow backspace-d on one of my parentheses :| Thanks for the answer though! I didn't know the query parameters also needed a `*` in the URL for them.