# use setattribute to change color (in chat)

Tags: javascript, chat, setattribute

I want to change the chat window fontcolor/fontsize of the page [younow](http://www.younow.com/). I tried 2 'cssText' samples but I'm unable to change the font color to RED. How can I change the chat window font color to RED? I'm using Firefox and greasemonkey.

```
sample 1:
document.getElementById("chatcomments").style.cssText = 'font-size: 36px; color: red !important;'

sample 2:
document.querySelector(".chatcomments span").style.cssText = 'font-size: 36px; color: red !important;'
```

[click to see the chatimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaEUB.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to make a browser extension/custom JavaScript to modify the page client-side?

Comment: Is it possible there is another style that is conflicting with it?  It could be that the style sheet is setting a style as important for that element.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Yes I want to make a custom JavaScript (I use Firefox and greasemonkey)

Comment: @Heiko Please see my edit...

Answer (score 2):

you need to be specific with the attributes of the style object:

```
document.getElementById("chatcomments").style.color    = "red";
document.getElementById("chatcomments").style.fontSize = "30px";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery, you can use the `css` function, like so:

```
$(".chatcomments > span").css("color", "red");
```

You do not need to set `font-size` again if it already has been set. Another issue is that `.chatcomments span` won't work as they're two different things; instead, `>` will work: `.chatcomments > span`.

It is also better to use RGB or hexadecimal values instead of colour names, for example:

```
$(".chatcomments > span").css("color", "#EE4B38"); //RGB
$(".chatcomments > span").css("color", "rgb(238, 75, 56)"); //Hex
```

In the case that you're trying to create a custom client-side script in Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey (it looks like you are), you must use `// @require` to import the JQuery source ([as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859092/2422013)):

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: how can I use your JQuery code in greasemonkey? I'm using Firefox and greasemonkey.

Comment: your JQuery code doesn't work - did you try your code on younow.com?

Comment: @Heiko Please take a screenshot of your developer console.

Comment: there was ONE red highlighted error in firefox developer console when I used the jquery 1.9.1 version you posted. Then I used the 1.10.1 jquery version (the errror vanished then). But: the code doesn't change font color to RED. -Did you try your code on younow.com?

Comment: @Heiko Did you use my instructions to **not** use `red`?

Comment: @Heiko If you continue to be rude, I will not help you. What happens if you apply to just `span` (and use the RGB red that I provided you with, you're currently using black).

Comment: I used: $(".chatcomments > span").css("color", "#EE0000"); and this doesn't change the color to red.

Comment: @Heiko Please read my reply again: `$("span").css("color", "rgb(255,0,0)");`

Comment: works with jquery 1.11.0 (meaning all font colors are red now). But unfortunately if a user writes a comment to the chat, the new font color will be black. Hmm, seems I have to start a new thread for this new problem.

Comment: @Heiko It seems that it refreshes the `iframe` rather than doing a proper fetch & update (lazy programming), there's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

el.style.setProperty('color', 'red'); seems more right