# Userscript working in Chrome/Firefox console but not as script

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm writing a small userscript that hides recommended videos in the sidebar for the new material beta design in jquery. it works in firefox and chrome developer console but not in greasemonkey or tampermonkey. i've tried //run-at document-idle,

```
 $(function(){
});
```

but it still doesnt work :/. m current code is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        j,m
// @namespace   hjgfn
// @description g
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLuBPKSnsxc
// @version     1
// run-at       document-idle
// @grant       none
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$(function(){
   $(".style-scope ytd-compact-video-renderer:contains('Empfohlenes Video')").hide();
});
```

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure that jquery is loading? Try just running an alert or something simple in pure javascript and see if that works. If it does, then it's likely that jquery isn't loading.

Comment: Also, see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey - to make sure you can use `@require`

Comment: I've used `$(document).ready(function(){
        if (jQuery) {  
          // jQuery is loaded  
          alert("Yeah!");
        } else {
          // jQuery is not loaded
          alert("Doesn't Work");
        }
      });` and it shows that it's loaded

Comment: `if ('undefined' == typeof window.jQuery) {
    alert("1")
} else {
    alert("0")
}` shows its not loaded

Comment: I have got it to working  with the waitforkeyelements library :)